# Align an element to bottom with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a `div` with some children:

```
<div class="content">
  <h1>heading 1</h1>
  <h2>heading 2</h2>
  <p>Some more or less text</p>
  <a href="/" class="button">Click me</a>
</div>
```

and I want the following layout:

```
 -------------------
|heading 1          |
|heading 2          | 
|paragraph text     |
|can have many      |
|rows               |
|                   |
|                   |
|                   | 
|link-button        |
 -------------------
```

Regardless how much text is in the `p` I want to stick the `.button` always at the bottom without taking it out of the flow. I've heard this can be achievable with Flexbox but I can't get it to work.

Comment: @Jonathan the wrapper does not have a fixed height. If I take it out the flow it would overlap the text

Comment: @supersize old Q but you could have given the wrapper `position:relative` - it's goofy because I think it's relative by default but you have SET it in order for the child's absolute positioning to be contained. Then `bottom:0` will fit flush.

Comment: Jacksonkr is right, this is the BEST solution, others are too long, too convoluted or not working the right way

Comment: @Jacksonkr the default position of a div is `static` not `relative`.

Comment: I realize this is an old thread at this point, but Jonathan's suggestion should be renamed to `position`, not `postition`.

Comment: Your premise isn't correct: "Regardless how much text is in the p I want to stick the .button always at the bottom without taking it out of the flow". If you stick the element to the bottom you are effectively taking it out of the flow, no matter how you did it.

Answer (score 1001, accepted):

You can use [auto margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#auto-margins)

> Prior to alignment via [`justify-content`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#propdef-justify-content) and [`align-self`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#propdef-align-self),
>   any positive free space is distributed to auto margins in that
>   dimension.

So you can use one of these (or both):

```css
p { margin-bottom: auto; } /* Push following elements to the bottom */
a { margin-top: auto; } /* Push it and following elements to the bottom */
```

```css
.content {
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
h1, h2 {
  margin: 0;
}
a {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <h1>heading 1</h1>
  <h2>heading 2</h2>
  <p>Some text more or less</p>
  <a href="/" class="button">Click me</a>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can make the element before the `a` grow to fill the available space:

```css
p { flex-grow: 1; } /* Grow to fill available space */
```

```css
.content {
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
h1, h2 {
  margin: 0;
}
p {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <h1>heading 1</h1>
  <h2>heading 2</h2>
  <p>Some text more or less</p>
  <a href="/" class="button">Click me</a>
</div>
```

Comment: For me, this works in Chrome, but not in Safari on iOS 10.2.  Can anyone confirm?

Comment: @Oriol I like this approach, but not the side effect of losing collapsing margins, what would you do about this?

Comment: flex-grow worked for me.  Here's how I did it `html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#site-content {
 flex: 1;
}`

Comment: Also a side note, remember to `height: 100%` on the parent element of which you are trying to push something to bottom with `margin-top: auto;`

Comment: "any positive free space is distributed to auto margins in that dimension." it's little things like this that are so elegant, for me this solution was 2 lines of code based on your answer. thank you :)

Comment: This will not work if you have too much content which will push out the button. My solution is to use flex and put a wrapper around the main content: `body{ display: flex; flex-direction: column; height: 100%; } .content-wrapper { flex-grow: 1; position: relative; overflow: auto;} .content { position: absolute; width: 100% }`

Comment: this is good but it will screw up any margin-top already in place, Timo's answer below yelds better result if you want perfectly dynamic position

Comment: I was able to get this to work with the combination of this post and [this article](http://www.lottejackson.com/learning/an-equal-height-grid-using-flexbox). Minor adjustments to the articles codepen gives [this codepen](https://codepen.io/TJSoftware/pen/povdZBZ).

Comment: `{ margin-bottom: 0px;
 margin-top: auto; }` will align to bottom

Answer (score 217):

You can use display: flex to position an element to the bottom, but I do not think you want to use flex in this case, as it will affect all of your elements.

To position an element to the bottom using flex try this:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.button {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

Your best bet is to set position: absolute to the button and set it to `bottom: 0`, or you can place the button outside the container and use negative `transform: translateY(-100%)` to bring it in the container like this:

```css
.content {
    height: 400px;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
.button {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Check this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d6hk7vjc/1/)

Comment: if you want it at the bottom, make sure to set the flex-direction to column.

Comment: What if I cannot provide the height?

Comment: What worked for me was just:
```
. content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

<div class="content"><a class="bottom">Something</a></div>
```

Answer (score 164):

**1. Style parent element: `style="display:flex; flex-direction:column; flex:1;"`**

**2. Style the element you want to stay at bottom: `style="margin-top: auto;"`**

**3. Done! Wow. That was easy.**

Example:

[image]

```css
section {
  /* ONLY FOR DEMO, NOT NECESSARY */
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

div {
  /* PARENT ELEMENT */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}

button {
  /* TARGET ELEMENT */
  margin-top: auto;
}

/* DECORATIVE STYLES FOR DEMO */

button {
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: crimson;
  color: white;
  border-style: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

section {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: crimson;
}

div {
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: khaki;
  border: 2px dashed black;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  min-width: 400px;
  min-height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor s at mi imperdiet fringilla vitae id lorem. Donec ut semper sapien, et ullamcorper metu</span>
    <button>I</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span
    ><button>
      stay
    </button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span
      >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi at augue ac turpis fringilla egestas. quis mi diam. Quisque faucibus, massa non finibus iaculis, arcu nulla auctor enim, quis accumsan dolor odio quis turpis. Duis convallis pulvinar justo sit amet feugiat.
      Duis sed lectus at mi imperdiet fringilla vitae id lorem. Donec ut semper sapien, et ullamcorper metu</span
    >
    <button>
      at
    </button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span
    ><button>
      bottom
    </button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi at augue ac turpis fringilla egestas. Donec quis mctus at mi imperdiet fringilla vitae id lorem. Donec ut semper sapien, et ullamcorper metu</span>
    <button>
      always
    </button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi at augue ac turpis fringilla egestas. Donec quis mctus at mi imperdiet fringilla vitae id lorem. Donec ut semper sapien, et ullamcorper</span
    ><button>
      all ways
    </button>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 103):

The solution with `align-self: flex-end;` didn't work for me but this one did in case you want to use flex:

## Result

```
 -------------------
|heading 1          |
|heading 2          | 
|paragraph text     |
|                   |
|                   |
|                   | 
|link button        |
 -------------------
```

## Code

***Note:** When "running the code snippet" you have to scroll down to see the link at the bottom.*

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 300px;
}

.content .upper {
  justify-content: normal;
}

/* Just to show container boundaries */
.content .upper, .content .bottom, .content .upper > * {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="upper">
   <h1>heading 1</h1>
   <h2>heading 2</h2>
   <p>paragraph text</p>
  </div>

  <div class="bottom">
   <a href="/" class="button">link button</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: content is the column container it holds 2 other container, with justify-content: space-between; you tell the flexbox to push the container away from each other how much as possible (in this case limited by the height of the content container)

Comment: that's not the real result, it will have space between each item (hence the name)

Comment: @Barbz_YHOOL No, it works if you increase the container height (see updated example)

Comment: After searching a lot, this is just perfect! Thank you.

Comment: With a little modification, this answer worked perfectly for me, thank you

Comment: alright, now it works, it's "hacky" in a sense (or smarty) but it yelds the cleanest result. Basically you divide in two divs, then you justify-content: space-between, so div 1 is at the top and div 2 is at the bottom. Then you put all the elements you want in div1 and only 1 element in div2. This part is useless tho `justify-content: normal;`

Answer (score 18):

When setting your display to **flex**, you could simply use the `flex` property to mark which content can grow and which content cannot.

[Flex property](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex/)

```css
div.content {
 height: 300px;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}

div.up {
  flex: 1;
}

div.down {
  flex: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="up">
    <h1>heading 1</h1>
    <h2>heading 2</h2>
    <p>Some more or less text</p>
  </div>

  <div class="down">
    <a href="/" class="button">Click me</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: note to myself: Remember to set the height in the container. I was struggling and in my scenario all I was missing was to set height: 100%

Answer (score 14):

**If it's fine to modify your HTML**, you can wrap all your top elements in a separate `div` and then use `justify-content: space-between`.

Something like this:

```html
<div class="content">
  <div>
    <h1>heading 1</h1>
    <h2>heading 2</h2>
    <p>Some more or less text</p>
  </div>
  <a href="/" class="button">Click me</a>
</div>
```

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Not sure about flexbox but you can do using the position property.

set parent `div` `position: relative`
and child element which might be an `<p>` or `<h1>` etc.. set `position: absolute` and `bottom: 0`.

Example:

index.html

```html
<div class="parent">
  <p>Child</p>
</div>
```

style.css

```css
.parent {
  background: gray;
  width: 10%;
  height: 100px;    
  position: relative;
}
p {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

[Code pen here.](https://codepen.io/sannjayshr555/pen/OdNLBX)

Comment: `position:fixed` wouldn't work because then it wouldn't be relative to the container it is in. Perhaps you meant `position:absolute`?

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
<div class="content">
    <h1>heading 1</h1>
    <h2>heading 2</h2>
    <p>Some more or less text</p>
    <a href="/" class="button">Click me</a>
</div>
```

Notes for CSS:

1. Change the height of `.content` as you need
2. Button will take the whole empty area at the bottom because of the `flex:1` property, making the whole area clickable. I will advise wrapping the button in a div or span

CSS

```
.content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100vh;
}

.button {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    align-items: flex-end;
}
```

https://codepen.io/alokjain_lucky/pen/MWooJGw

Answer (score 1):

I just found a solution for this.

for those who are not satisfied with the given answers can try this approach with flexbox

**CSS**

```
    .myFlexContainer {
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .myFlexChild {
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;

        /* 
         * set this property if this is set to column by other css class 
         *  that is used by your target element 
         */
        flex-direction: row;

        /* 
         * necessary for our goal 
         */
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        height: 500px;
    }

    /* the element you want to put at the bottom */
    .myTargetElement {
        /*
         * will not work unless flex-wrap is set to wrap and 
         * flex-direction is set to row
         */
        align-self: flex-end;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
    <div class="myFlexContainer">
        <div class="myFlexChild">
            <p>this is just sample</p>
            <a class="myTargetElement" href="#">set this to bottom</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<section>
  <div class="top">
    <div class="search-box">
         ... bla-bla-bla 
    </div>
    <div class="processing">
      Do something...
    </div>
  </div>

  <button class="select-lesson">
    Select Lesson
  </button>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
section {
display:flex;
flex-direction: column;
}

section {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background: yellow;
  color: blue;
  padding: 1.8em;
  border-radius: 1.4em;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  margin: 25px 0;

 /* This line does the trick */ 
 justify-content: space-between;
}

.top {
  width: 100%;
}

button.select-lesson, .search-box {
  border-radius: 0.6em;
}

.search-box {
  padding: 1.6em 1.7em;
  background: #232323;
}

.search-box svg {
  display: block;
}

.processing {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4.5em 0;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

button.select-lesson {
  border: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #14274B;
  color: #9FB8EA;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding: 1.7rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
content{
  display:flex; 
  flex-direction:column; 
  justify-items:space-between; 
  heigh:100vh
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try This

```css
.content {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      height: 250px;
      width: 200px;
      border: solid;
      word-wrap: break-word;
    }

   .content h1 , .content h2 {
     margin-bottom: 0px;
    }

   .content p {
     flex: 1;
    }
```

```html
   <div class="content">
  <h1>heading 1</h1>
  <h2>heading 2</h2>
  <p>Some more or less text</p>
  <a href="/" class="button">Click me</a>
</div>
```