# Position last flex item at the end of container

Tags: css, flexbox

This question concerns a browser with full css3 support including flexbox.

I have a flex container with some items in it. They are all justified to flex-start but I want the *last* `.end` item to be justified to flex-end. Is there a good way to do this without modifying the HTML and without resorting to absolute positioning?

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  outline: 1px solid green;
  min-height: 400px;
  width: 100px;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
p {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p class="end"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes. See `auto` margin illustrations  here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Align an element to bottom with flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31000885/align-an-element-to-bottom-with-flexbox)

Answer (score 599, accepted):

> [**Flexible Box Layout Module - 8.1. Aligning with auto margins**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#auto-margins)
>
> Auto margins on flex items have an effect very similar to auto margins in block flow:
>
> - During calculations of flex bases and flexible lengths, auto margins are treated as 0.
> - Prior to alignment via `justify-content` and `align-self`, any positive free space is distributed to auto margins in that dimension.

Therefore you could use `margin-top: auto` to distribute the space between the other elements and the last element.

This will position the last element at the bottom.

```
p:last-of-type {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  min-height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
}
p {
  height: 30px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 5px;
}
p:last-of-type {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

[image: vertical example]

---

Likewise, you can also use `margin-left: auto` or `margin-right: auto` for the same alignment horizontally.

```
p:last-of-type {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
p {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 5px;
}
p:last-of-type {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

[image: horizontal example]

Comment: ah perfect, can't believe I missed that! Especially embarrassing since I *totally* know about the using-margin-auto-to-center-vertically trick and use it all the time

Comment: @j08691 I don't have a formal explanation as to *why* it works, but it's similar to how you can use `margin: 0 auto` for horizontal centering. Flexbox items respect the margin, and I believe that `margin: auto` will essentially position the item with as much space between the sibling as possible. See: http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#auto-margins

Comment: @jo8691 if I'm not mistaken, `margin: auto` on a flex item tells it to create as much space as possible in that direction.

Comment: [The spec says](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#auto-margins) `Prior to alignment via justify-content and align-self, any positive free space is distributed to auto margins in that dimension.`

Comment: I'm trying to learn more about flexbox so it would be great to see a reference that describes this behavior. Particularly that it's also intended and not a quirk or side effect.

Comment: @j08691, `auto` margins are part of the flexbox spec. Definitely not a quirk or side effect. See my question and answer for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276

Comment: I would like to add something to the answer. In iPhone 5s, 8.3 this doesn't work. A fix I found in another stackoverflow question, is that adding `flex-grow: 1;` to the last element before the last item to position at the end, fixes it.

Comment: @JoshCrozier I know this is an old post, but I think it could do with an example of how to keep the 3 blocks aligned in the center and the last one pushed to the end, I did it by using `margin-top: auto` on the top block as well as the bottom one.

Comment: Talk about counter-intuitive. One of those 'once told never forgotten' quirks of CSS

Comment: I don't understand why justify-self: end; can't be used in this situation and we must use margin auto. It's really weird.

Answer (score 106):

## This flexbox principle also works horizontally

During calculations of flex bases and flexible lengths, auto margins
 are treated as 0. 
 Prior to alignment via justify-content and
 align-self, any positive free space is distributed to auto margins in
 that dimension.

**Setting an automatic left margin for the Last Item will do the work.**

```
.last-item {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

[image]

**Code Example:**

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
  outline: 1px solid black;
}

p {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.last-item {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p class="last-item"></p>
</div>
```

[Codepen Snippet](https://codepen.io/DavidBendahan/pen/VQZxGO)

**This can be very useful for Desktop Footers.**

[image]

As *Envato* did here with the company logo.

[Codepen Snippet](https://codepen.io/DavidBendahan/pen/VQZxGO)

Comment: Unsure why this actually works, but it helped me on a project.

Comment: What if I need that all items will be in center and the last one at the right side?

Comment: There's a variation of this but with centered items: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59405567/2394994