# Center one and right/left align other flexbox element

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I would like to have `A` `B` and `C` aligned in the middle.

How can I get `D` to go completely to the right?

BEFORE:

[image]

AFTER:

[image]

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
li {
  display: flex;
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #aaa;
}
li:last-child {
  background: #ddd;
  /* magic to throw to the right*/
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
  <li>D</li>
</ul>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/z44p7bsx/

Comment: "li" doesn't need display: flex in its css rules.

Answer (score 510, accepted):

Below are five options for achieving this layout:

- CSS Positioning
- Flexbox with Invisible DOM Element
- Flexbox with Invisible Pseudo-Element
- Flexbox with `flex: 1`
- CSS Grid Layout

---

### Method #1: CSS Positioning Properties

Apply `position: relative` to the flex container.

Apply `position: absolute` to item D.

Now this item is absolutely positioned within the flex container.

More specifically, item D is removed from the document flow but stays within the bounds of the [*nearest positioned ancestor*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Absolute_positioning).

Use the CSS offset properties `top` and `right` to move this element into position.

```css
li:last-child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #ddd;
}
ul {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
li {
  display: flex;
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #aaa;
}
p {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0;
}
span {
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
  <li>D</li>
</ul>
<p><span>true center</span></p>
```

**One caveat** to this method is that some browsers may not completely remove an absolutely-positioned flex item from the normal flow. This changes the alignment in a non-standard, unexpected way. More details: *[Absolutely positioned flex item is not removed from the normal flow in IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32991051/3597276)*

---

### Method #2: Flex Auto Margins & Invisible Flex Item (DOM element)

With a combination of [**`auto`** margins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276) and a new, invisible flex item the layout can be achieved.

The new flex item is identical to item D and is placed at the opposite end (the left edge).

More specifically, because flex alignment is based on the distribution of free space, the new item is a necessary counterbalance to keep the three middle boxes horizontally centered. The new item must be the same width as the existing D item, or the middle boxes won't be precisely centered.

The new item is removed from view with `visibility: hidden`.

In short:

- Create a duplicate of the `D` element.
- Place it at the beginning of the list.
- Use flex `auto` margins to keep `A`, `B` and `C` centered, with both `D` elements creating equal balance from both ends.
- Apply `visibility: hidden` to the duplicate `D`

```css
li:first-child {
  margin-right: auto;
  visibility: hidden;
}
li:last-child {
  margin-left: auto;
  background: #ddd;
}
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
li {
  display: flex;
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #aaa;
}
p { text-align: center; margin-top: 0; }
span { background-color: aqua; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>D</li><!-- new; invisible spacer item -->
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
  <li>D</li>
</ul>
<p><span>true center</span></p>
```

---

### Method #3: Flex Auto Margins & Invisible Flex Item (pseudo-element)

This method is similar to #2, except it's cleaner semantically and the width of `D` must be known.

- Create a pseudo-element with the same width as `D`.
- Place it at the start of the container with `::before`.
- Use flex `auto` margins to keep `A`, `B` and `C` perfectly centered, with the pseudo and `D` elements creating equal balance from both ends.

```css
ul::before {
  content:"D";
  margin: 1px auto 1px 1px;
  visibility: hidden;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #ddd;
}
li:last-child {
  margin-left: auto;
  background: #ddd;
}
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
li {
  display: flex;
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #aaa;
}
p { text-align: center; margin-top: 0; }
span { background-color: aqua; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
  <li>D</li>
</ul>
<p><span>true center</span></p>
```

---

### Method #4: Add `flex: 1` to left and right items

Starting with Method #2 or #3 above, instead of worrying about equal width for the left and right items to maintain equal balance, just give each one `flex: 1`. This will force them both to consume available space, thus centering the middle item.

You can then add `display: flex` to individual items in order to align their content.

***NOTE*** *about using this method with `min-height`:* Currently in Chrome, Firefox, Edge and possibly other browsers, the shorthand rule `flex: 1` breaks down to this:

- `flex-grow: 1`
- `flex-shrink: 1`
- `flex-basis: 0%`

That **percentage unit (%)** on `flex-basis` causes this method to break when `min-height` is used on the container. This is because, as a general rule, percentage heights on the children require an explicit `height` property setting on the parent.

This is an old CSS rule dating back to 1998 ([CSS Level 2](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-CSS2-20080411/)) which is still in effect in many browsers to some degree or another. For complete details see [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33636796/3597276) and [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276).

Here's an illustration of the problem posted in the comments by [user2651804](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2651804/user2651804):

```css
#flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: teal;
  width: 150px;
  min-height: 80vh;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#flex-container>div {
  background: orange;
  margin: 5px;
}

#flex-container>div:first-child {
  flex: 1;
}

#flex-container::after {
  content: "";
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="flex-container">
  <div>very long annoying text that will add on top of the height of its parent</div>
  <div>center</div>
</div>
```

The solution is to not use the percentage unit. Try `px` or just nothing at all ([which is what the spec actually recommends](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-common), despite the fact that at least some of the major browsers have appended a percentage unit for whatever reason).

```css
#flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: teal;
  width: 150px;
  min-height: 80vh;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#flex-container > div {
  background: orange;
  margin: 5px;
}


/* OVERRIDE THE BROWSER SETTING IN THE FLEX PROPERTY */

#flex-container > div:first-child {
  flex: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
}

#flex-container::after {
  content: "";
  flex: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
}


/* OR... JUST SET THE LONG-HAND PROPERTIES INDIVIDUALLY

#flex-container > div:first-child {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
}

#flex-container::after {
  content: "";
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
}
 */
```

```html
<div id="flex-container">
  <div>very long annoying text that will add on top of the height of its parent</div>
  <div>center</div>
</div>
```

---

### Method #5: CSS Grid Layout

This may be the cleanest and most efficient method. There is no need for absolute positioning, fake elements or other hackery.

Simply create a grid with multiple columns. Then position your items in the middle and end columns. Basically, just leave the first column empty.

```css
ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr repeat(3, auto) 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 5px;
  justify-items: center;
}

li:nth-child(1) { grid-column-start: 2; }
li:nth-child(4) { margin-left: auto; }

/* for demo only */
ul { padding: 0; margin: 0; list-style: none; }
li { padding: 5px; background: #aaa; }
p  { text-align: center; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
  <li>D</li>
</ul>
<p><span>| true center |</span></p>
```

Comment: _"The new item must be the same width as the existing D item, or the middle boxes won't be precisely centered."_ - that sucks that it must be the same width, but thank god for CSS grid :)

Comment: Using the Grid technique, the items aren't in the dead centre, is there a way to get the logo element to be dead in the centre? https://imgur.com/a/SVg9xsj

Comment: To get the Grid layout method to work on the vertical axis, besides the obvious, it needs only one extra line:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72440616/all-items-centered-along-the-vertical-axis-except-the-last-which-should-sit-on-t

Comment: Hi @Michael Benjamin I have a question about the BFC - do the flex and grid items stay in the Normal Flow? My doubt arises MAINLY because flex-direction: column stacks the flex items VERTICALLY like a Block Formatting Context does - Thanks in advance, I guess the comment doesn't really fit the question but I need someone amazing in CSS like you.

Comment: @Daniel, Perhaps post a complete question with examples, so you can get a complete answer. But, generally speaking, unless you apply absolute positioning (i.e., `position: absolute` or `position: fixed`) to a flex / grid item, it remains in the normal document flow.

Comment: Great @Michael Benjamin then it will remain in the normal flow only DISTRIBUTED with a Grid Layout/Flexbox Layout (as the case may be) instead of a Block Layout, right?

Comment: How would you use the grid layout, having an element on the left and just one centred element in the middle? The centred element having a max-width and width: 100%.

Comment: Method #1 ftw, clean and simple.

Comment: Another downside of #1 is that on small screens, D will show in front of ABC.

Answer (score 51):

The simplest solution will be to justify-content center to the parent container and giving margin-left auto to first and last child element.

```css
ul {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
}


.a,.d {
  margin-left:auto;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="a">A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
  <li class="d">D</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @RedGuy11 can you share what you did?

Comment: Unfortunately A/B/C will be centred within the *remaining* space by this method. In other words, even if there's room for them to be centred with respect to the full width, they won't be.

Answer (score 13):

**Most easy way**

```css
.box{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
}
.item1{
   flex:1;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   transform: translateX(10px);/*D element Width[if needed]*/
}
```

```html
 <div class="box">
   <div class="item1">
      <div>A</div>
      <div>B</div>
      <div>C</div>
   </div>
   <div class="item2">D</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Needing to use the exact px width of the element could be problematic

Answer (score 11):

Using the `display:grid` approach, you can simply put all of the `ul` children into the same cell and then set `justify-self`:

```css
.ul {
  display: grid;
}

.ul > * {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  justify-self:center;
}

.ul > *:last-child {
  justify-self: right;
}

/* Make Fancy */
.li {
  display:inline-block;
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #bbb;
}
```

```html
<div class='ul'>
  <span>
     <span class='li'>A</span>
     <span class='li'>B</span>
     <span class='li'>C</span>
  </span>
  <span class='li'>D</span>
</div>
```

Comment: @cdoublev I changed `ul` and `li` to divs with classes to make it valid.

Comment: Seems cleanest and easiest given the specific question asked.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it aligned, you can simply attach an empty span and split the three child spans into them.

Comment: can you provide a short demo to back-up your statement?

Comment: don't use the extra HTML just for achieving something in look and feel, can break your page in other browsers

Answer (score -1):

Inspired by the [Method #5: CSS Grid Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38948646/1075499) of [@Michal Benjamin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3597276/michael-benjamin)'s solution and because I'm using Tailwind and as of now still don't have access to all the grid options by default. This seems to work:

```css
ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(0, 1fr));
}

li {
  align-self: center;
}

li:nth-child(1) {
  justify-content: flex-start; /* OR margin-right: auto */
}

li:nth-child(3) {
  justify-content: flex-end; /* OR margin-left:auto */
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
</ul>
```

PS: Not sure if mixing up flex and grid like this is a good idea!

Comment: you are not mixing grid and flex, justifty-content is a CSS grid property AND flexbox property (same for align-self)

Comment: Also grid and flex are designed to work together.

Comment: I attempted to make sense of your CSS in a snippet demo. You had invalid comment markup and a stray colon. Feel free to revise if it's not right.

Answer (score -1):

**The easiest way:**

```css
.wrap {
    display:flex;
}
.full-width {
    width: 100%;
}
.centered {
    display: flex;
    justify-content:center;
}
.btn {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: end;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
   <div class="full-width"></div>
   <div class="full-width centered">
      <div>A</div>
      <div>B</div>
      <div>C</div>
   </div>
   <div class="full-width btn">D</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: This completely changes the markup, and as such can hardly be considered "the easiest way".

Answer (score -2):

The accepted answer can be changed a bit because you can use grid template areas and do it without fake element

```
grid-template-areas '. b c'
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr
```

Comment: Feel free to copy the snippet and make your changes. Also, a link to a specific answer is better than a potentially obsolete reference to the accepted answer.

Answer (score -3):

Very clear question. I couldn't help but post the answer after a few hours of digging. We Could of solved this with tables, table-cell, absolute positions, transforms but we just had to do it with flexbox :)

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.center {
  margin: auto;
}
```

http://codepen.io/rgfx/pen/BLorgd

Comment: This doesn't truly center the middle items because it only factors in the *remaining* space, not the *entire* space. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QKGrRk

Comment: @Michael_B, your right didn't notice that, my bad. Back to using absolute positions :( Maybe with your high rep you should set a bounty get this resolved for good. I would but I have a very low rep, even lower now trying to help you.

Comment: No bounty is going to add a new behavior to the flexbox model, the, by Michael_B, given answer is as good as it gets...today.

Answer (score -5):

I expanded on [Michael_B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3597276/michael-b)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38948646/476951)

```css
.center-flex__2-of-3 > :nth-child(1), .center-flex__2-of-3 > :nth-child(3) {
  flex: 1;
}
.center-flex__2-of-3 > :nth-child(1) {
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
.center-flex__2-of-3 > :nth-child(3) {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
.center-flex__1-of-2 > :nth-child(1) {
  margin: auto;
}
.center-flex__1-of-2 > :nth-child(2) {
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
.center-flex__2-of-2 > :nth-child(1) {
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
.center-flex__2-of-2 > :nth-child(2) {
  margin: auto;
}
.center-flex__1-of-2:before, .center-flex__1-of-1:before {
  content: '';
  flex: 1;
}
.center-flex__1-of-1:after, .center-flex__2-of-2:after {
  content: '';
  flex: 1;
}

[class*=center-flex] {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 10px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
[class*=center-flex] > * {
  display: flex;
}

li {
  padding: 3px 5px;
}
```

```html
2 of 3
<ul class="center-flex__2-of-3">
  <span>
    <li>Accusamus</li>
    <li>Porro</li>
  </span>
  <span>
    <li>Center</li>
    <li>this</li>
  </span>
  <span>
    <li>Accusamus</li>
    <li>Porro</li>
    <li>Culpa</li>
    <li>Sit</li>
  </span>
</ul>

<br><br>
1 of 2
<ul class="akex center-flex__1-of-2">
  <span>
    <li>Center</li>
    <li>this</li>
  </span>
  <span>
    <li>Accusamus</li>
    <li>Porro</li>
    <li>Culpa</li>
    <li>Sit</li>
  </span>
</ul>

<br><br>
2 of 2
<ul class="akex center-flex__2-of-2">
  <span>
    <li>Accusamus</li>
    <li>Porro</li>
    <li>Culpa</li>
    <li>Sit</li>
  </span>
  <span>
    <li>Center</li>
    <li>this</li>
  </span>
</ul>

<br><br>
1 of 1
<ul class="center-flex__1-of-1">
  <span>
    <li>Center</li>
    <li>this</li>
  </span>
</ul>
```

[Here with the help of SASS as a codepen](https://codepen.io/HerrSerker/pen/dQxMdO?editors=1100)

Comment: Your list markup is invalid. A span can't be the child of a list.

Answer (score -5):

```css
ul { 
  padding: 0; 
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
li {
  display: flex;
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #aaa;
}
li:last-child {
  background: #ddd;
  position:absolute;
  right:10px;

}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
  <li>D</li>
</ul>
```