# Flex box alignment of left and centre elements

Tags: css, flexbox

```css
   #xxx {
      position:relative;
      display:flex;
      height:32px;
      width:150px;
      background-color:black;
      color:white;
      font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; 
      justify-content: center;
      margin-left:10px;
   }
   #xxx > span {
      align-self: center;
   }
   #xxx > img{
      margin-right:auto;
   }
```

```html
   <body>
      <div id="xxx"><img src="xxx.png" height="32" width="32"/><span>hello</span></div>
   </body>
```

I have been try to get the following to align properly. I'm trying to have the image left aligned and the text within the span centered. At first I tried to position the span with absolute and set left:0; but that messed up. Then I tried the margin:auto  but that messed up the centre aligned element.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
   <style>
   #xxx {
      position:relative;
      display:flex;
      height:32px;
      width:150px;
      background-color:black;
      color:white;
      font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; 
      justify-content: center;
      margin-left:10px;
   }
   #xxx > span {
      align-self: center;
   }
   #xxx > img{
      margin-right:auto;
   }

   </style>
   <body>
      <div id="xxx"><img src="xxx.png" height="32" width="32"/><span>hello</span></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: paulie i didn't like the answer to the question that you have marked this a duplicate on it wasn't clear to me

Comment: something like https://jsfiddle.net/link2pk/5m1br2e5/ ?

Comment: thanks link2pk that's the best so far. Can you please provide that as an answer

Comment: once a question is marked as duplicate then SO restricts answering that question, i think

Comment: @MarMan29, see [**this post**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38948102/3597276), and box #66 in [**this post**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276).

Comment: wow i'm surprised. Thanks for everyone's contributions i honestly thought there would be a simpler way they all seem like $hitty hacks to me. I think the best solution is absolute positioning with a calculated offset after all...

Comment: Flexbox can't do everything. Scratch that. *CSS* can't do everything. Hence, hacks have been around since the beginning of time. Tables/floats for layout. OL/UL for navigation. And now, fake elements for equal balance in a flex container. Life isn't perfect, but $hit gets done ;-)

Comment: Absolute positioning is one option. Just keep in mind that it removes the element from the document flow, which may lead to overlap with surrounding elements. Pseudo-elements, as I describe in my links above, stay in-flow without breaking semantics. Good luck!

Comment: Hahah thanks Michael_B yes you're right ;) Thanks for the responses and yes I have offset the left margin to counter the absolute not taking up space. Cheers mate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
#xxx {
      position:relative;
      display:flex;
      height:32px;
      width:150px;
      background-color:black;
      color:white;
      font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; 
      margin-left:20px;
   }
    span {
      align-self: center;
      margin-left:25%;


   }
  img{
  position:relative;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
     <body>
      <div id="xxx"><img src="http://www.imagenspng.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/yoshi-super-mario-01.png" height="32" width="32"/>
        <span>hello</span>
       </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Gowtham but isn't it the margin-left in your answer that did the alignment?

Comment: Ya Marman i tried different ways but this one worked out, since i have given in percentage it wont affect responsiveness

Comment: Yes but it seems like a hack solution no offence. What's the point of having the justify-content: center; if we just use the margin to offset?

Comment: Sorry it was a typo error,i have removed it ,just look into it.

Comment: The problem is if the width or image dimensions change the margin set needs to be re-calculated as it's no longer correct....