# How can I horizontally align 2 spans in the same line?

Tags: css

I have 2 spans in the same line with several elements in each one.

How can I add css styles to my 2 spans and make one be centered, the other one in the same line shouldn't move the previous one (centered), but it should bind to its right corner.

[image: image description]

**HTML**

```
    <span><!-- should be centered--> 
      <a id="3"></a><span id="2"> ..... </span> 
      <a id="1">...</a>
    </span>

    <span><!-- left corner of this span should meet the right corner of the previous span -->
      <label>something</label><input type="text" id="5">
      <input type="button" />
    </span>

    <span class="mrRight"><!-- float right here --> ...... </span>
```

Comment: can you provide your code ?

Comment: you mean span1 should be center aligned & span2 should be right aligned on the same line horizontally ?

Comment: Nikhil Nanjappa  correct

Comment: do you have a wrapper to these spans ? Better provide the HTML as well to help

Comment: @Nikhil Nanjappa 
`code`<span ><!-- should be centered-->
        <a id="3"></a>
        <span id="2">
           ..... 
        </span>
        <a id="1">...</a>
    </span>
    <span> <!-- left corner of this span should meet the right corner of the previous span -->
        <label>something</label>
        <input type="text" id="5">
        <input type="button" />
    </span>
    <span class="mrRight"><!-- float right here -->
        ......
    </span>
`code`

Comment: Try with CSS flexbox: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38948102/3597276

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the first spans margin-left to 48%. Or if you want to be precise, margin-left: calc(50% -  x), where x is half of the width of the first span.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/VilleKoo/73Ljhhaj/)

Note: the gradient is there just to show you where the center is :)

```
.center { margin-left: calc(50% - 26px) }
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this firstly you need to add a wrapper around the spans like so

**HTML**

```
<div class="span_wrapper">
  <span> 
    <a id="3"></a><span id="2"> center </span> 
    <a id="1">center</a>
  </span>

  <span>
    <label>something</label>
    <input type="text" id="5"> <input type="button" />
  </span>

  <span class="mrRight"> right </span> 
</div>
```

Now the appropriate **CSS** should be

```
.span_wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}

.span_wrapper .mrRight{
  float: right;
}
```

```css
.span_wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}

.span_wrapper .mrRight{
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="span_wrapper">
  <span> 
    <a id="3"></a><span id="2"> center </span> 
    <a id="1">center</a>
  </span>

  <span>
    <label>something</label>
    <input type="text" id="5"> <input type="button" />
  </span>

  <span class="mrRight"> right </span> 
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't do what I need to do. How can I add a picture? I think that would be better.

Comment: here - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85516/embed-image-in-stackoverflow

Comment: please have a look at the picture. I wanted the first span to be centered and the second one to be at the right to it and not move it to the left.

Comment: Ok i see, working on it - Added your image in the question itself not as part of the answer.