# Flex Container CSS. How to move one element to left?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've created a flex container like this

[image]

And this is the CSS for the flex container

```
.flexcontainer {
   display: -webkit-flex;
   display: flex;
   -webkit-flex-direction: row;
   flex-direction: row;
   -webkit-justify-content: center;
   justify-content: center;
}
```

So, I would like to know is it possible to change the place of the first flex item to left using the flex properties?

Comment: Maybe it's just me but your question has totally confused me.. You want to for simplistic say... move box one to box 2's position?

Comment: I would like to move only the first box to left

Comment: I'm not sure how the accepted answer in any way answers the question above. But maybe I'm missing something. Here's what I thought you meant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38948102/3597276

Comment: @Michael_B exactly. Thanks