# Centering two divs in a wrapper

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

I am trying to center `#left` and `#center` inside `#wrapper` like this:

[image]

I am trying to get `#center` to be in the actual center of `#wrapper` both horizontally and vertically, and that `#left` will be in a slight margin to his left. How do I achieve that?

```css
.c {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 60vw;
  height: 80vh;
  margin-top: 13vh;
}

#wrapper {
  height: 13vh;
  margin-top: 2vh;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

#center {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 12vw;
  height: 10vh;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#left {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 13vh;
  height: 13vh;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="c">
  <div>content content content</div>
  <div>content content content</div>

  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left">left</div>
    <div id="center">center</div>


  </div>
  <div>content content content</div>
  <div>content content content</div>
```

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y6r585jk/2/

Answer (score 2):

You know the width of `#left`. It's 13vh.

Add a pseudo-element on the right with the same width.

Then center all three elements in the container.

The pseudo is a counter-balance to `#left`. It enables `#center` to be perfectly centered.

You can hide the pseudo with `visibility: hidden`.

```css
.c {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 60vw;
  height: 80vh;
  margin-top: 13vh;
}

#wrapper {
  height: 13vh;
  margin-top: 2vh;
  border: 1px solid blue;

  /* new */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; /* center children horizontally */
  align-items: center;     /* center children vertically */
}

/* new */
#wrapper::after {
  content: 'right';
  width: 13vh;
  border: 1px dashed black;
  /* visibility: hidden; */
}

#center {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 12vw;
  height: 10vh;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0 5px; /* new */
}

#left {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 13vh;
  height: 13vh;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="c">
  <div>content content content</div>
  <div>content content content</div>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left">left</div>
    <div id="center">center</div>
  </div>
  <div>content content content</div>
  <div>content content content</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y6r585jk/4/

The layout can also be achieved using an actual (DOM) element or absolute positioning.

More details here: [Center and right align flexbox elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38948102/3597276)

Answer (score 1):

You can use flexbox

```css
.c {
border: 1px solid black;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 60vw;
    height: 80vh;
    margin-top: 13vh;
}
#wrapper {
  display : flex;
  justify-content : center;
  align-items : center;
    height: 13vh;
    margin-top: 2vh;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
#center {
    display: inline-block;
    width:12vw;
    height:10vh;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
#left {
    display: inline-block;
    width:13vh;
    height:13vh;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class = "c">
<div>content content content</div> 
<div>content content content</div> 

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left">left</div>
    <div id="center">center</div>
</div>
<div>content content content</div> 
<div>content content content</div>
```

Comment: Oh and you add the margin wanted

Comment: This solution does not truly center the `#center` element. It centers *both* elements in the container, which aligns `#center` at center-right. https://jsfiddle.net/y6r585jk/3/

Comment: That's the trick, otherwise this question would have an easy answer (and 1,000 duplicates). https://jsfiddle.net/y6r585jk/4/

Comment: the title misled me

Answer (score 1):

A non-flexbox solution would be to give the center element `position: relative`, center it in the container using `text-align: center`, and give the left element `position: absolute` and a `right` setting of `calc(50% + 7vw)` (resulting in 1 vw distance to the center element - you can change that as you like):

```css
.c {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 60vw;
  height: 80vh;
  margin-top: 13vh;
}

#wrapper {
  height: 13vh;
  margin-top: 2vh;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  text-align:center;
}

#center {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 12vw;
  height: 10vh;
  margin-top: 1vh;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}

#left {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  right: calc(50% + 7vw);
  width: 13vh;
  height: 13vh;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="c">
  <div>content content content</div>
  <div>content content content</div>

  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left">left</div>
    <div id="center">center</div>
  </div>
  <div>content content content</div>
  <div>content content content</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for your problem..

First apply some flex attributes to the wrapper to center the items..

```
#wrapper {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-content: center;
border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

THis putts everything in the center..

next use align-eslf to center vertically.

```
#center {
display: inline-block;
align-self: center;
```

Finally add the margin.. I have added 1% to test..

```
#center {
display: inline-block;
align-self: center;
margin-left: 1%;
```

I have this..

[image]

Comment: judging by your image, you centered both center and left. what i asked is for center to be centered and that left will be to it's left side.

Comment: My apologies.. it looked similar to the picture..it is a tough one this..

Answer (score 0):

The only way i can satisfy this answer is with smart margins to center tthe center element..

I feel like there has to be a better way but I'm sure I have tried every combination.. lol

anyhow..

CSS - I added an extra wrapper for the right hand side..

margin-left: 5% on the #left
margin-left: 15% on wrapper_r

You can easily calculate the absolute center by adjusting these margins..

```
                          .c {
              border: 1px solid black;
              margin-left: auto;
              margin-right: auto;
              width: 60vw;
              height: 80vh;
              margin-top: 13vh;
            }


          .wrapper1 {
          display: flex;
          justify-content: flex-start;
          border: 1px solid blue;    }


        #left {
              margin-left: 5%;
        width: 13vw;
        height: 13vh;
        border: 1px solid green;
      }

          #wrapper_r {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      margin-left:15%

          }
          #center {
          flex: 1;
        width: 12vw;
        height: 10vh;
        border: 1px solid red;
      }
```

HTML

```
          <div class="c">
            <div>content content content</div>
            <div>content content content</div>


          <div class="wrapper1">
              <div id="left">left</div>

            <div id="wrapper_r">
              <div id="center">center</div>


            </div></div>


            <div>content content content</div>
            <div>content content content</div>
```

I hope this works for you and I hope if there is a better solution with Flexbox It is posted here..

Your layout might be more suited or grid or a smarter mind :)

[image]