# Vertically align two paragraphs on one line, one in center one on right

Tags: css, html, text-alignment

according to W3Schools

> The `align` attribute is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead.

I am wondering how on earth, can I simply align two paragraphs within one line.

I am open to flex box solutions, but, I do not need a third dummy paragraph to behave as a starting point. Also, producing a row and columns seems to overcomplicating this ?simple? task?

This is what I have come up with so far, thus `text-align` does nothing...:

```css
p {
  display: inline-block;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
}

.right {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="center">Center</p>
  <p class="right">Right</p>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38948102/3597276

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with the ***Flexbox*** and `position` *property*:

```css
.container {
  position: relative; /* needs to be on the parent */
  display: flex; /* displays flex-items (children) inline */
  justify-content: center; /* centers them horizontally */
  align-items: center; /* and vertically */
}

.container > .right {
  position: absolute; /* needs to be on the child */
  right: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 480px) { /* adjust */
  .container {
    flex-direction: column; /* stacks flex-items vertically */
  }
  .container > .right {
    position: static; /* back to default */
    align-self: flex-end; /* aligns to the horizontal end */
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="center">Center</p>
  <p class="right">Right</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
p {
   display: inline-block;
}

.center {
  margin-left:50%;

}

.right {
  float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question. You should add some percentage width to your two paragraphs and then add `float:right;` to both of them. Also, don't forget to keep the .right paragraph above the .center paragraph in your html.

See the below snippet for reference.

```css
p {
  display: inline-block;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
  width: 33.3333%;
  float: right;
}

.right {
  text-align: right;
  width: 33.33333%;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="right">Right</p>
  <p class="center">Center</p>
  
</div>
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

With the litlle description you gave, there is little to answer.

to start:

With `flex` I would do :

```css
.container {
display:flex;
}
.center {
  flex:1;
  text-align: center;
}

.right {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="center">Center</p>
  <p class="right">Right</p>
</div>
```

With the `table-layout` *(IE8 & +)* , I would do

```css
.container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

p {
  display: table-cell;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;/* will use whole space avalaible*/
}

.right {
  text-align: right;
  width: 5em;/* a small value to shrink it on its content */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="center">Center</p>
  <p class="right">Right</p>
</div>
```

with `grid`, I would do

```css
.container {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:1fr auto;
}


.center {
  text-align: center;
}

.right {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="center">Center</p>
  <p class="right">Right</p>
</div
```

I would not use `float` nor `inline-block` where elements can wrap to the next line any time *(unless max-width is set for both elements)* ;)

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution:

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.center {
  display: inline-block;
}

.right {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

With `position: absolute` applied on `.right`, you can move the paragraph wherever you want within the next parent element that has `position: relative` (If no parent has `position` set, the element will relate to the window).

The reason why text-align is not working in your case, is because of `display: inline-block`.

Some basics you need to know:

- A paragraph element is just a form of a container. The text in it is basically another element itself.
- `text-align` aligns the content within an element. Hence, the text gets aligned to the borders of the paragraph element.
- The default value for a paragraph element is `display: block`. That means its width spans over the entire width of its parent element (or the window in case no container is declared). Hence, `text-align` will have a visible effect.
- `display: inline-block` will make the borders of the element it is applied on shrink to the size of its content. Since `text-align` affects the content, not the element itself, your paragraph element won't move.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but that actually drops .right to the next line, and I wanted to have two paragraphs on one line.

Comment: True, somehow it appeared on the same line when I tried the code. However, in that case you can set .center and .right to display: inline-block and it will work perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
.container {
  display:grid;
}

p {
  display: inline-block;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
}

.right {
  text-align: right;
}

.left {
  text-align: left;
}

<div class="container">
  <p class="center">Center</p>
  <br>
  <p class="right">Right</p>
  <br>
  <p class="left">Left</p>
</div>
```