# How to vertically align elements inside of the navigation bar?

Tags: html, css

I have created navigation bar that contains links for different tabs and drop down for the menu. I'm having problem to vertically align all elements inside of the navigation bar. Seems that select tag caused some of the problems. Here is example of my outline:

```css
header.headerBox {
 width: 100%;
 height: 80px;
 border-top: 2px solid #000099;
 border-right: 2px solid #000099;
 border-left: 2px solid #000099;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000099;
 background-color: #87CEFF;
}
h1.mainTitle {
 color: #000099;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0px;
 padding-top: 5px;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
}
nav.xNavigation {
 height: 100%;
 color: #000099;
 border-top: 2px solid #000099;
 margin: 0px;
 padding-top: 2px;
 padding-left: 5px;
 padding-right: 5px;
 padding-bottom: 2px;
}
nav.xNavigation a {
 color: #000099;
 text-decoration: none;
 cursor: pointer;
 font-weight: bold;
}
nav.xNavigation select {
 float: right;
}
nav.xNavigation a:hover {
 color: white;
}
```

```html
<header class="headerBox">
  <h1 class="mainTitle">Single Page Application</h1>
  <nav class="xNavigation">
    <a href="#" id="tab1">Tab 1</a> |
    <a href="#" id="tab2">Tab 2</a> |
    <a href="#" id="tab3">Tab 3</a> |
    <a href="#" id="tab4">Tab 4</a> |
    <select name="menu" id="menu">
      <option value="mainBox" selected="selected">Home</option>
        <option value="settingsBox">Settings</option>
    </select>
  </nav>
</header>
```

As you can see in the snippet above elements are not vertically aligned. I'm not sure if there is a good way to organize the elements. If anyone can help please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I vertically center text with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458/how-do-i-vertically-center-text-with-css)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are open to using flexbox you can make a few adjustments and create the layout you want.

example

```css
header.headerBox {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  border: 2px solid #000099;
  background-color: #87CEFF;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
h1.mainTitle {
  color: #000099;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
nav.xNavigation {
  color: #000099;
  border-top: 2px solid #000099;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
nav.xNavigation a {
  color: #000099;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
}
nav.xNavigation select {
  margin-left: auto;
}
nav.xNavigation a:hover {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<header class="headerBox">
  <h1 class="mainTitle">Single Page Application</h1>
  <nav class="xNavigation">
    <a href="#" id="tab1">Tab 1</a> |
    <a href="#" id="tab2">Tab 2</a> |
    <a href="#" id="tab3">Tab 3</a> |
    <a href="#" id="tab4">Tab 4</a> |
    <select name="menu" id="menu">
      <option value="mainBox" selected="selected">Home</option>
        <option value="settingsBox">Settings</option>
    </select>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I use flex box just in the header how that would affect the rest of the page?

Comment: If you make the header (or class you are targetting) a flex container it should only affect the contents of the header.

Comment: What should be updated in order to set a tags to the center instead of being on the left side?

Comment: You can use the `justify-content` property. Which element are you trying to center? This guide is a good introduction --> https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: a elements. They should be in the center. Thanks for the link!

Comment: Have a look at this great answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/38948646/5561605 -- You have a few options

Answer (score 1):

It's because you set a fixe height ;)

```css
header.headerBox {
     width: 100%;
     border-top: 2px solid #000099;
     border-right: 2px solid #000099;
     border-left: 2px solid #000099;
      border-bottom: 2px solid #000099;
     background-color: #87CEFF;
    }
    h1.mainTitle {
     color: #000099;
     text-align: center;
     margin: 0px;
     padding-top: 5px;
     padding-bottom: 5px;
    }
    nav.xNavigation {
      display:flex;
      flex-flow: row wrap;
      align-items: center;
     color: #000099;
     border-top: 2px solid #000099;
     margin: 0px;
     padding-left: 5px;
     padding-right: 5px;
      padding-top: 10px;
      padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    nav.xNavigation a {
     color: #000099;
     text-decoration: none;
     cursor: pointer;
     font-weight: bold;
    }
    nav.xNavigation select {
     display:flex;
        flex-flow: row wrap;
        justify-content: flex-end;
    }
    nav.xNavigation a:hover {
     color: white;
    }
    .select-container {
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: row wrap;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        padding-top: -20px;
        margin-top: -20px;
     }
```

```html
    <header class="headerBox">
      <h1 class="mainTitle">Single Page Application</h1>
        <nav class="xNavigation">
        <a href="#" id="tab1">Tab 1</a> |
        <a href="#" id="tab2">Tab 2</a> |
        <a href="#" id="tab3">Tab 3</a> |
        <a href="#" id="tab4">Tab 4</a> |
        <div class='select-container'>
          <select name="menu" id="menu">
          <option value="mainBox" selected="selected">Home</option>
            <option value="settingsBox">Settings</option>
        </select>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
```

Comment: Can we keep select on the very left side by any chance?

Comment: I edited my answer check that please :) If it's ok for you please give a green flag