# flex alignment incorrect result

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to align a line of text to the bottom of the screen with this code.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

div.BottomAligned {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="Main" style="min-height: 100%;">
  <div>
    Line1<br> Line2
  </div>
  <div id="Bottom" class="BottomAligned">
    TextBottom
  </div>
</div>
```

However, the "TextBottom" text is shown *below* the visible portion of the screen, so the height of the Main div is actually bigger than 100% of the window size. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: True horizontal centering for the bottom text: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38948102/3597276

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin:0; /* Don't forget to remove default margin */
}
#Main {
  display: flex; /* Main should be the flex container */
  flex-direction:column;
}

div.BottomAligned {
  margin-top:auto; /* Push items to bottom */
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div id="Main" style="min-height: 100%;">
  <div>
    Line1<br> Line2
  </div>
  <div id="Bottom" class="BottomAligned">
    TextBottom
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In addition, I recommend the article https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ to understand flexbox

Comment: This breaks center alignment for the text in the bottom. No obvious ways to fix it.

Comment: @user626528 text-align:center :)

Comment: I thought about justify-content: center, but it didn't work for some reason.

Comment: @user626528 it works only if the container is flex ;) but no need here

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't want to use flexbox, you can just replace the CSS with the below:

```
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div.BottomAligned {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
}

#Main {
  position: relative;
  height:100vh;
}
```