# Center and right/left align items in a NativeScript Layout

Tags: nativescript

In the context of a NativeScript app, I've been struggling to find an efficient, non-hacky way to do what seems pretty simple: have one item in the center of a layout, and another item all the way to the right or left of the layout--something like the images in this question: [Center and right align flexbox elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38948102/center-and-right-align-flexbox-elements). The items should all be in a single row as they are there. (I've looked through those solutions, but I don't want to add a pseudo-element, and a lot of CSS just doesn't work with NativeScript.) Is there some kind of clean, canonical way to do this with the default layouts?
In case this isn't "specific" enough, say I have a scenario like this:

```
<SomeLayout>
  <Label text="Center me"></Label>
  <Label text="Pull me to the right"></Label>
</SomeLayout>
```

The text properties of the labels describe what I'm looking for. Please test any suggestions or be sure that they work.

Comment: what if there is no space to set `center me` and `pull me to the right` in one single line?

Comment: @bhavinjalodara just assume there is definitely enough space. So the text might just be "c" and "r" for the labels, and the font size very small, guaranteeing that space won't be an issue

Comment: Is there a particular reason you don't just want to use Flexbox to achieve this? Make the container flex, center the first label and add ``margin-left: auto;`` to the second label fill in the extra space with margin.

Comment: @CodeSpent I can easily do this with [HTML/CSS](https://jsfiddle.net/thm0er28/1/). However, it won't work with NativeScript's FlexboxLayout (even with `display: flex`, which isn't necessary in a FlexboxLayout). They're limited in what they can do because it has to have correlates in iOS and Android

Comment: Actually, I was in a rush and didn't check that against the goal here; I forgot to center the first item... but the margin tricks fail in NativeScript anyway

Answer (score 30, accepted):

you can use `horizontalAlignment` with `GridLayout` by applying same row number to both the labels.

```
<GridLayout rows="auto" columns="*">
  <Label row="0" horizontalAlignment="center" text="Center me" class="center"></Label>
  <Label row="0" horizontalAlignment="right" text="Pull me to the right" class="right"></Label>
</GridLayout>
```

you can also set `horizontalAlignment` property from CSS by using `horizontal-align` attribute.

```
.center{
    horizontal-align:center;
}
.right{
    horizontal-align:right;
}
```

main trick is that you have to give same row number to labels so that they overlap each other.

Comment: Perfect! I'd only tried this in a horizontal StackLayout, which doesn't work at all. This is a huge help

Answer (score 0):

There are pre-defined classes in NativeScript that can handle left/center/right alignement. In order to align right you could use "**text-right**" class. There is more here https://v7.docs.nativescript.org/ui/theme#class-names

It is for V7 but working for V8 as well