# justify-self css property does not produce a desired effect

Tags: html, css, flexbox

`justify-self` is not working. Why?

html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="a">

  </div>
  <div class="b">

  </div>
  <div class="b">

  </div>

</div>
```

css

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background: yellow;
}

.container * {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: green;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.a {
  justify-self: start;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oobarbazanoo/1ukfd4nc/)

I would expect the first element to be aligned to left since it has class `a` and class `a` specifies `justify-self: start`, but that does not happen. Why?

As I was informed in comments flexbox does not support the `justify-self` property. Then how could I position two of children in middle of the parent and one child stick to the left side of the parent using for example grid?

Comment: *In flexbox layouts, this property is ignored* This only works for grid. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-self

Comment: @Gerard, thank you. I will change my question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't need grid for this.
Flexbox is made for one dimensional layouts and Grid is made for two dimensional layouts.

You can do this in multiple ways. Michael_B explained this very good in this similar question [center-and-right-align-flexbox-elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38948102/center-and-right-align-flexbox-elements)

Comment: this is more suitable as a comment than an asnwer .. basically you are simply linking to another question