# How to use different align on same row with CSS flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How to use different align on same row with CSS flex?

I have this:

```css
.buttons-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons-container">
  <button mat-raised-button>A</button>
  <button mat-raised-button>B</button>
  <button mat-raised-button>C</button>
</div>
```

My result is:

```
                                 | (center)
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                              A B C                                  |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
                                 | (center)
```

But I need align C to right:

```
                                 | (center)
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                               A B                                 C |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
                                 | (center)
```

**IS IT IMPORTANT TO KEEP** `div` and `button`

I try other code but KO

```css
.buttons-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}
.buttons-container>button:last-child {
  flex: 1;
  justify-self: end;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons-container">
  <button mat-raised-button>A</button>
  <button mat-raised-button>B</button>
  <button mat-raised-button>C</button>
</div>
```

none of the proposed solution on [Center and right align flexbox elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38948102/center-and-right-align-flexbox-) does work with buttons in a div

```css
.buttons-container div::before {
  content:"D";
  margin: 1px auto 1px 1px;
  visibility: hidden;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #ddd;
}
.buttons-container button:last-child {
  margin-left: auto;
  background: #ddd;
}
.buttons-container div {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.buttons-container button {
  display: flex;
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #aaa;
}

/* true center */
p    { text-align: center; position: relative; }
span { background-color: aqua; }
p::before {
  content: "\2191";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons-container">
  <button mat-raised-button>A</button>
  <button mat-raised-button>B</button>
  <button mat-raised-button>C</button>
</div>
```

```css
.buttons-container button:first-child {
  margin-right: auto;
  /*visibility: hidden; */
}
.buttons-container button:last-child {
  margin-left: auto;
  background: #ddd;
}
.buttons-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.buttons-container button {
  display: flex;
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #aaa;
}

/* true center */
p    { text-align: center; position: relative; }
span { background-color: aqua; }
p::before {
  content: "\2191";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons-container">
  <button mat-raised-button>A</button>
  <button mat-raised-button>B</button>
  <button mat-raised-button>C</button>
</div>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-self

Comment: `justify-self` do not wot on only one element

Comment: @Michael_B, your duplicate post is not the same case, I do not have `ul` and `li`. I have any `button` in a `div`

Comment: `.buttons-container button:first-child,
.buttons-container button:last-child {
  margin-left: auto;
}`

Also, in your edited solution, the `justify-self: end;` is doing nothing. The `flex: 1` stretches the button to cover all available space, so there's nothing to justify.

Comment: @HenriqueErzinger, thank you, your solution work it

Comment: @sgrillon, the duplicate is perfectly suitable for this question. It provides five solutions which you can use. The HTML is irrelevant; the CSS can be applied to any series of elements.

Comment: And the solution provided by @HenriqueErzinger is not useful and does not work. It results in the A & B elements not perfectly centered due to the unequal distribution of free space on either side ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/bfugqpmk/)). For a complete explanation of the problem and, again, five solutions, see the duplicate post.

Comment: @Michael_B, why do you not post an answer here?

Comment: @sgrillon because the purpose of a duplicate is to avoid repeating the same answer. He already provided a canonical answer that cover your case and even more

Comment: sorry, but I could not understand the answer with the other post because the answer is too long

Comment: @Michael_B, I edit my post with yours proposal but do not work with `button` in a `div`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/eL1wrt3g/