# Center main navigation and right align the cart

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying to get the following header in the cleanest way possible. I'm not really bothered if it is via CSS Grid or Flexbox, as long as the solution isn't hacky.

[image]

I have tried to do this with Flexbox, but I'm stuck, here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<nav>
  <div class="container nav__body">
    <ul class="nav__links">
      <li><a href="#" class="nav__link">Products</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="nav__link">Our Story</a></li>
      <li><a href="index.html" class="nav__link nav__logo">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="nav__link">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="nav__link">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#" class="nav__cart">Cart</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

nav {
  background-color: #ACD038;
  height: 100px;
}

.container {
  width: 1024px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: grey;
  height: 100%;
}

.nav__body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav__links {
  display: flex;
  background-color: firebrick;
}

.nav__link {
  padding: 5px 20px 5px 0;
  color: #fff;
}
```

I have also created [a Codepen](https://codepen.io/Ciwan/pen/jOOXVMK).

Comment: The technique used here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38948102/center-and-right-align-flexbox-elements does not quite center it 100%. https://imgur.com/a/SVg9xsj

Comment: It looks perfectly centered in your image. Not sure what the problem is.