# position elements in a horizontal line while one of them is placed at the center

Tags: html, css

I want to create a simple footer. I need the copyright text at the center and two links at the right side (all three elements should be horizontally positioned)

So far they position above each other.

How can I fix this?

```css
#myFooter .footer-copyright {
    background-color: #333333;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

#myFooter .row {
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}

#myFooter .navbar-brand {
    margin-top: 45px;
    height: 65px;
}

#myFooter .footer-copyright p {
    margin: 10px;
    color: #ccc;
}

#myFooter ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<footer id="myFooter">
<div class="footer-copyright">

<ul>
  <li><a href="#">First</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Second</a></li>
</ul>
                    
                    
    <p>copyright goes here...</p>
</div>
 </footer>
```

Comment: Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38948102/center-and-right-align-flexbox-elements for various methods to achieve what you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add to all elements

`display: inline-block;`

To elements you want to position left and right give them :

`position: absolute;`

`left: 0; // or if you want right use right: 0;`

Comment: @foxer you need to separate li elements, give them id's and in css access both of them separately and give them left: 0; and right: 0;

Answer (score 1):

> I want to create a simple footer [...] copyright text at the center
>   and two links at the right side

One approach to achieving this is to use **CSS Grid**.

In the CSS Grid below, I have:

- Created a grid with a single row and three columns
- placed the `.copyright` in the center cell
- placed the `.links` in the right-hand cell
- horizontally centered the contents of each grid cell, using `justify-items: center;`
- vertically centered the contents of each grid cell, using `align-items: center;`

**Working Example:**

```css
footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 60% 20%;
  grid-template-rows: 100%;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100px;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-color: rgb(0, 191, 0);
}

.copyright {
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3;
}

.links {
  grid-area: 1 / 3 / 2 / 4;
}

.links a {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

```html
<footer>

<p class="copyright">&copy; Copyright Goes Here</p>

<ul class="links">
  <li><a href="#">First</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Second</a></li>
</ul>

</footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

on their parent element give the style `display: flex;` 
this will arrange the elements in a row, use `justify-content: center` and `align-items: center` to align the items at the center of the parent both horizontally and vertically, but the links will still be vertically aligned, give the parent element of the links, ie the `<ul></ul>` the style `display: flex;` too. Hope this helps.