# Center and right align flexbox elements with text-oveflow and taking empty space on left side

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

@michael-benjamin [Center and right align flexbox elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38948646) almost what I want, but with 2 differences:

1. Div have to take empty space at left side too (when it be wide)
2. Div have to collapse text when there is no empty space around at all.

**What I have?**

[image]

`A` is main centered object and `BBBBBBBBBBBBBBB` is right object.

This is fine till `A` will grow:

[image]

**What I want?**

[image]

**Is it possible to do with flex/grid/table-tr-td/any other css tricks?**

**What I tried?**

1. CSS Positioning Properties - can't stop when grow to `B`
2. Flex Auto Margins & Invisible Flex Item (DOM element) - invisible item don't give empty space at left side
3. CSS Grid Layout - `1fr` don't give empty space at left side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS grid can do it like below:

```css
.container {
  margin: 10px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr minmax(0,max-content) 1fr;
  color: #fff;
}
.container::before {
  content:"";
}

.b {
  margin-left: auto;
  background: grey;
}

.a {
  margin: auto;
  background: blue;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
  max-width:100%;
}



body {
  background:linear-gradient(red,red) center/ 2px 100% no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="a">AA</div>
  <div class="b">BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="a">AA</div>
  <div class="b">BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="a">AAAAAAAAAAAAAA</div>
  <div class="b">BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="a">AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</div>
  <div class="b">BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="a">AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</div>
  <div class="b">BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB</div>
</div>
```