# Keep profile picture on the right side in flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the below code that I'm attempting to make responsive and I can't seem to figure out how to keep the profile picture to the right on FlexBox. Now `col-md-auto` is on the left, and I want it to be on the right side as soon as mobile hits.

On large screens, it's on the right but as soon as I hit mobile, it pushed the `col-md-auto` class to the left and I'd like to keep it to the right.

All help would be appreciated!

**Please click on the "Run snippet"**.

```css
/* Core */
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    text-align: left;
    background: #fff;
    background-size: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
}

a {
    color: #007bff;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    -webkit-text-decoration-skip: objects;
}

a:-webkit-any-link {
    color: -webkit-link;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

body .jupiterx-site {
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: #212529;
}

[type=search] {
    outline-offset: -2px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

input, button {
    overflow: visible;
}

input, button {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
}

button {
    -webkit-appearance: button;
}

button {
    border-radius: 0;
}

button {
    text-transform: none;
}

/* Header */
header, nav {
    display: block;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .jupiterx-navbar-desktop-left {
        text-align: left;
    }
    .navbar-expand-md {
        -ms-flex-flow: row nowrap;
        -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
        -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        flex-flow: row nowrap;
        -webkit-box-pack: flex-start;
        -ms-flex-pack: flex-start;
        justify-content: flex-start;
    }
    .navbar-expand-md > .container {
        -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
    }
    .jupiterx-navbar-desktop-left .jupiterx-navbar-brand {
        margin-right: 1rem;
        -webkit-box-flex: 1;
        -ms-flex-positive: 1;
        flex-grow: 1;
    }

    /* Top Navigation - Right Side */
    .navbar-expand-md .navbar-collapse {
        display: -webkit-box!important;
        display: -ms-flexbox!important;
        display: flex!important;
        -ms-flex-preferred-size: auto;
        flex-basis: auto;
    }

    .jupiterx-navbar-desktop-left .jupiterx-search-form {
        margin-left: 1rem;
    }

    .col-md {
        -ms-flex-preferred-size: 0;
        flex-basis: 0;
        -webkit-box-flex: 1;
        -ms-flex-positive: 1;
        flex-grow: 1;
        max-width: 100%;
    }

    .col-md-auto {
        -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
        -webkit-box-flex: 0;
        flex: 0 0 auto;
        width: auto;
        max-width: none;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 767.98px) and (min-width: 576px) {
    .jupiterx-navbar-tablet-left {
        text-align: left;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
    .form-inline .form-control {
        display: inline-block;
        width: auto;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
}

.navbar {
    position: relative;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: space-between;
    -ms-flex-pack: space-between;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.navbar > .container {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: space-between;
    -ms-flex-pack: space-between;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-brand {
    color: whitesmoke;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.navbar-brand {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: .3125rem;
    padding-bottom: .3125rem;
    margin-right: 1rem;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    line-height: inherit;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

/* Top navigation */
.jupiterx-header {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 100%;
}

.jupiterx-site-navbar {
    padding-top: .30rem;
    padding-bottom: .30rem;
    -webkit-transition: padding .15s;
    transition: padding .15s;
    background-color: #2f689f;
}

.jupiterx-site-navbar > div {
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.jupiterx-site-navbar .jupiterx-navbar-brand-link {
    margin-right: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    max-width: 1140px;
}

/* Top Navigation - Right Side */
.jupiterx-site-navbar .navbar-collapse {
    -ms-flex-direction: inherit;
    -webkit-box-orient: inherit;
    -webkit-box-direction: inherit;
    flex-direction: inherit;
    -webkit-box-pack: flex-end;
    -ms-flex-pack: flex-end;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

.collapse:not(.show) {
    display: none;
}

.navbar-collapse {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 100%;
    flex-basis: 100%;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex-positive: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.jupiterx-site-navbar .jupiterx-search-form {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.jupiterx-search-form {
    position: relative;
}

.form-inline {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.jupiterx-site-navbar .jupiterx-search-form .form-control {
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 4px;
    width: 250px;
}

.jupiterx-search-form .form-control {
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 2em;
}

.form-control {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: .375rem .75rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #495057;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid #ced4da;
    border-radius: .25rem;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
    -webkit-transition: border-color .15s ease-in-out,-webkit-box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
    transition: border-color .15s ease-in-out,-webkit-box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
    transition: border-color .15s ease-in-out,box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
    transition: border-color .15s ease-in-out,box-shadow .15s ease-in-out,-webkit-box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
}

.btn:not(:disabled):not(.disabled) {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.jupiterx-search-form button {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    color: #6c757d;
    font-size: .875rem;
    padding-top: .65rem;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    padding: .375rem .75rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    border-radius: .25rem;
    -webkit-transition: color .15s ease-in-out,background-color .15s ease-in-out,border-color .15s ease-in-out,-webkit-box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
    transition: color .15s ease-in-out,background-color .15s ease-in-out,border-color .15s ease-in-out,-webkit-box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
    transition: color .15s ease-in-out,background-color .15s ease-in-out,border-color .15s ease-in-out,box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
    transition: color .15s ease-in-out,background-color .15s ease-in-out,border-color .15s ease-in-out,box-shadow .15s ease-in-out,-webkit-box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
}

.jupiterx-search-form button:before {
    line-height: 0;
}

.jupiterx-icon-search-1:before {
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    content: "\f002";
}

[class*=" jupiterx-icon-"]:before, [class^=jupiterx-icon-]:before {
    /*font-family: jupiterx;*/
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    speak: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 1;
}

::before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Bottom Header */
.sh-subheader {
    padding-top: 1rem;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
    background: whitesmoke;
    background-size: auto;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-top-style: solid;
}

.row {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}

.col-md, .col-md-auto {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}

/* Align items vertically */
.align-vertically {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

/* Circle profile picture on  */
.sh-profile-picture {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    max-width: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

#mega-menu-wrap-secondary-menu #mega-menu-secondary-menu > li.mega-menu-item > a.mega-menu-link:first-child {
    padding-left: 0px;
}

.sh-user-name {
    color: #2f689f;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#mega-menu-wrap-secondary-menu .mega-menu-toggle.mega-menu-open + #mega-menu-secondary-menu {
    margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>

<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="profile" href="https://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/f692c9923b.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>

    <div class="jupiterx-site">

        <!-- Bottom banner -->
        <header class="sh-header" role="banner" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/WPHeader">
            <div class="sh-subheader">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md align-vertically">
                            <div class="jupiterx-subfooter-menu-container">
                                Menu
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-auto align-vertically">
                            <img class="sh-profile-picture" src="https://onedublin.files.wordpress.com/2010/10/penn-state-football-field.jpg" alt="profile picture">
                            <div class="sh-user-name"><?= $user->get_user_login(); ?></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
    </div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Center and right align flexbox elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38948102/center-and-right-align-flexbox-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.col-md has flex: 1 on it on large screens but it is removed on smaller screens.

you can add margin-left:auto; to col-md-auto and it will stay on the right side

```
.col-md-auto {
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

Comment: Works beautifully! Thanks @Nico.