# Nav links not being centered in Navbar from React Bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I'm creating a navbar for a website using React and React Bootstrap and the links are not being centered for some reason.

Here is a picture of what it looks like:
[image]

Notice the links "Home" and "Link" are not centered.

Here is the code:

```
import { Component } from "react";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import { Navbar, Nav, NavDropdown, Container } from "react-bootstrap"; 

export default class AppNavbar extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Navbar bg="light" expand="lg" style={{width: "100%"}}>
            <Navbar.Brand href="#home">React-Bootstrap</Navbar.Brand>
            <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
            <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
              <Nav className="mx-auto">
                <Nav.Link href="#home">Home</Nav.Link>
                <Nav.Link href="#link">Link</Nav.Link>
              </Nav>
            </Navbar.Collapse>
          </Navbar>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to center your navbarSupportedContent portion of your navbar is to add a pseudo-element on the right side of the navbar container and then styling the pseudo-element and the navbar-brand element with `flex: 1.` That will center the menu items.

This is based on the Method #4 portion of this previous answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38948646/1011984

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<style>
@media (min-width:768px) {
    .navbar-container-md::after {
        content:"Right side block so flex can center the ul";
        margin: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
        background: #ddd; /* color is so the element can be seen if hidden is disabled */
        display: flex;
        flex: 1;
    }

    .navbar-brand {
        flex: 1;
        margin-right: 0;
    }
}
</style>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid navbar-container-md">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse flex-grow-0 align-self-center" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Links</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <p class="text-center">Middle</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I don’t use React, so I can’t set it up to be used in React, but it should be easy enough to go from the HTML code to what’s needed for React.