# Center a div to the right of an image inside a header

Tags: html, css

I want a header with an image attached to the left and a div with some text inside, to the right of this image. The div must contain horizontally and vertically centered text.

Something like that:
[image: 1]

I tried almost everything like relative positioning, float, inline-blocks and columns but I just can't figure out how.

```css
header {
  background-color: rgb(31, 31, 31);
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 20px 10px;
}

.header-right {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

#imageContainer {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a id="imageContainer">
    <img id="image" src="test.png">
  </a>
  <div class="header-right">
    <h1>Centered text here</h1>
  </div>
</header>
```

**EDIT**: someone closed the question saying that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38948102/center-one-and-right-left-align-other-flexbox-element) answer my question. But i have to center the text in the space between the image container and the very end of the header's width!

Comment: You are asking for a complete solution but the question tagged will help you think how to implement all of this. You would need to imagine the picture as a set of boxes and break it and try to think of it logically how to fit it. I will probably choose the flex solution to do this from the answer you mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path of least resistance for this particular case is probably just to use flex to keep the element count down. See below.

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgb(31, 31, 31);
  padding: 20px 10px;
}

header h1 {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <a>
        <img id="image" src="https://picsum.photos/200">
    </a>
    <h1>Centered text here</h1>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use display as flex instead of floats

```css
header {
    background-color: rgb(31, 31, 31);
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 20px 10px;
    display: flex;
}
.header-right {
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid white;
    width: 100%;
}
#imageContainer {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 12px;
    border: 1px solid white;
}

#imageContainer:hover, .header-right:hover {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <a id="imageContainer">
        <img id="image" src="test.png">
    </a>
    <div class="header-right">
        <h1>Centered text here</h1>
    </div>
</header>
```