# Center Align logo in MUI AppBar React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am trying to center align logo in AppBar. Really got stuck to achieve the logo alone at the center. Both vertical and horizontal.

Here is my AppBar.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { styled, useTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';

import MuiAppBar, { AppBarProps as MuiAppBarProps } from '@mui/material/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@mui/material/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';
import MenuIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Menu';

import logo from './../assets/images/logo_white.svg'
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import MoreIcon from '@mui/icons-material/MoreVert';
const drawerWidth = 240;



interface AppBarProps extends MuiAppBarProps {
  open?: boolean;
}

const AppBar = styled(MuiAppBar, {
    shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== "open"
  })<AppBarProps>(({ theme, open }) => ({
    transition: theme.transitions.create(["margin", "width"], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen
    }),
    ...(open && {
      width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
      marginLeft: `${drawerWidth}px`,
      transition: theme.transitions.create(["margin", "width"], {
        easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
        duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen
      })
    })
  }));



  export default function AppBar({ open, onDrawerOpen }:any) {
    const theme = useTheme();
  
    return (
      <AppBar position="fixed" style={{ background: "#002a5e" }} open={open}>
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="open drawer"
            onClick={onDrawerOpen}
            edge="start"
            sx={{ mr: 2, ...(open && { display: "none" }) }}
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography variant="h6" noWrap component="div">
            TITLE
          </Typography>

          <Box
            component="img"
            sx={{
            height: 32, 
            }}
            alt="MyLogo"
            src={logo}
        />

        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    );
  }
```

Now it just shows along with the  title text. Please help

Comment: You need to add that line in your code ```<Toolbar sx={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "center" }}>```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many possible approaches, as a basic example perhaps try add a container with `flex: 1` on both side of the logo.

This should always push the logo to the center of `Toolbar`, but still keep the button and title at the start of it, as it seemed to be the desired result.

Example:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { styled, useTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";

import MuiAppBar, { AppBarProps as MuiAppBarProps } from "@mui/material/AppBar";
import Toolbar from "@mui/material/Toolbar";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import IconButton from "@mui/material/IconButton";
import MenuIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Menu";

import logo from "./../assets/images/logo_white.svg";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import MoreIcon from "@mui/icons-material/MoreVert";
const drawerWidth = 240;

interface AppBarProps extends MuiAppBarProps {
  open?: boolean;
}

const AppBar =
  styled(MuiAppBar, {
    shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== "open",
  }) <
  AppBarProps >
  (({ theme, open }) => ({
    transition: theme.transitions.create(["margin", "width"], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
    }),
    ...(open && {
      width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
      marginLeft: `${drawerWidth}px`,
      transition: theme.transitions.create(["margin", "width"], {
        easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
        duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
      }),
    }),
  }));

export default function AppBar({ open, onDrawerOpen }: any) {
  const theme = useTheme();

  return (
    <AppBar position="fixed" style={{ background: "#002a5e" }} open={open}>
      <Toolbar>
        <Box sx={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center", flex: "1" }}>
          <IconButton
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="open drawer"
            onClick={onDrawerOpen}
            edge="start"
            sx={{ mr: 2, ...(open && { display: "none" }) }}
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography variant="h6" noWrap component="div">
            TITLE
          </Typography>
        </Box>
        <Box
          component="img"
          sx={{
            height: 32,
          }}
          alt="MyLogo"
          src={logo}
        />
        <Box sx={{ flex: "1" }}></Box>
      </Toolbar>
    </AppBar>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks  a lot for that and it worked great. But a stupid question if you dont mind.. Here for the box containing the title, you have specified alignItems center, even it is on the left and logo on the center where nothing is specified.. How is that?

Comment: @SandeepThomas `alignItems: "center"` here is just for aligning elements inside the `Box` vertically, some more about this property [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items).

Answer (score 1):

You need to pack `IconButton` and `Typography` in to a `Box` and set it's `display` to `absolute`. Then you can manage the logo with flex attributes.

```
export default function AppBarr({ open, onDrawerOpen }: any) {
  const theme = useTheme();

  return (
    <AppBar position="fixed" style={{ background: "#002a5e" }} open={open}>
      <Toolbar sx={{ justifyContent: "center" }}>
        <Box
          sx={{
            position: "absolute",
            display: "flex",
            alignItems: "center",
            right: "20px",
          }}
        >
          <IconButton
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="open drawer"
            onClick={onDrawerOpen}
            edge="start"
            sx={{ mr: 2, ...(open && { display: "none" }) }}
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography variant="h6" noWrap component="div">
            TITLE
          </Typography>
        </Box>

        <Box
          component="img"
          sx={{
            height: 32,
          }}
          alt="MyLogo"
          src={logo}
        />
      </Toolbar>
    </AppBar>
  );
}
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38948102/center-one-and-right-left-align-other-flexbox-element) is a good source to learn all the approaches you can take.

Comment: I tried and it pushed the logo to center but the title and icon pushed to the extreme right

Comment: @SandeepThomas You can change `right: "20px"` to place it where you want exactly.