# Specifying class for properties and styles for components and tags in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am pretty new to React. I was actually building an AppBar with a logo at center based on a suggestion in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74788445/954093)

```
    <Box sx={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center", flex: "1" }}>
      <IconButton
        color="inherit"
        aria-label="open drawer"
        onClick={onDrawerOpen}
        edge="start"
        sx={{ mr: 2, ...(open && { display: "none" }) }}
      >
        <MenuIcon />
      </IconButton>
      <Typography variant="h6" noWrap component="div">
        TITLE
      </Typography>
    </Box>
```

But is there is any best way of specifying a single class or constant for these settings outside the definition like this

```
<IconButton class='settings'>
```

instead of all this

[image]

Tried the way @Dimitriy suggested and below my code

```
export default function AppBar({ open, onDrawerOpen }:any) {
    const theme = useTheme();
    const iconButtonOptions = {
        color: "inherit",
        ariaLabel: "open drawer",
        onClick: onDrawerOpen,
        edge: "start",
        sx: {{ mr: 2, ...(open && { display: "none" }) }}
      }
    return (
        <AppBar position="fixed" style={{ background: "#002a5e" }} open={open}>
        <Toolbar>
            <Box sx={{ display: "flex",flexDirection:"row", alignItems: "center", flex: "1" }}>
            <IconButton {...iconButtonOptions} >
                <MenuIcon />
            </IconButton>
            <Typography variant="h6" noWrap component="div">
                TITLE
            </Typography>
            </Box>
            <Box
            component="img"
            sx={{
                height: 32,
            }}
            alt="MyLogo"
            src={logo}
            />
            <Box sx={{ flex: "1" }}></Box>
        </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
    );
  }
```

But its saying

> Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable '(Missing)'.ts(2451)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't define jsx component props through classes. But if you want to make your jsx more understandable, or avoid repetition, you can move all the props into an object.

```
const iconButtonOptions = {
  color: "inherit",
  ariaLabel: "open drawer",
  onClick: onDrawerOpen,
  edge: "start",
  sx: { mr: 2, ...(open && { display: "none" }) }
}

return (
  <IconButton {...iconButtonOptions}>
    <MenuIcon />
  </IconButton>
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that.. But I am getting an error cannot redeclare block scoped variable when I added that object before return. What could be the reason?

Comment: Could you share the code please?

Comment: my bad, unnecessary parentheses around sx. Updated my answer

Comment: Thanks for that update. But now another error at IconButton tag. Its saying No overload matches this call
<IconButton {...iconButtonOptions} >

Comment: Could you make a minimum reproduce example on codesandbox?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's actually is the way for that.

First, you can make a new object variable that will hold all of your props.
Example:

```
const iconBtnProps = {
   color: 'inherit',
   aria-label: 'open drawer',
   onClick: onDrawerOpen,
   edge: 'start',
   sx: { mr: 2, ...(open && { display: "none" }) }
};

// render the <IconButton /> component and spread the object
<IconButton {...iconBtnProps} />
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to check [styled-components](https://styled-components.com/). It would really make things easier for styling components.