# Pushing last list item to the bottom

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am using the [Vali Admin](http://pratikborsadiya.in/vali-admin/dashboard.html) theme and I am trying to push the last list item in the left sidebar to the bottom.

I have barely used flexbox before so I am not familiar with it at all, but I changed the menu to `display: flex` and then followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33924704/3120489) to try to push the last item to the bottom. I am trying to do *exactly* what the person in that question if after.

These are my modifications to the theme:

```
.app-menu {
  @extend .app-menu;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;

  li:last-of-type {
    margin-top: auto;
  }
}
```

Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kpagcha/schk8yrn/15/).

I think the problem is that the menu isn't using as much height as it can.

I would gladly include a working snippet but for the love of my I couldn't figure out how to create a jsfiddle. It doesn't allow local files and it would block my gist. Same with Codepen.

Comment: jsfiddle doesn't work with local file, you need to pull all the content inside

Comment: @TemaniAfif I tried pasting the whole theme CSS and the page just froze. It can't syntax highlight so much code.

Comment: please show the HTML code

Comment: you need to reduce your code to the minimal one, we don't need your full website

Comment: @TemaniAfif the theme needs to be included in order for everything to behave as it does...

Comment: we aren't going to inspect all your theme. You should do the effort to narrow your code to isolate the issue. Doing so you will probably find the solution alone.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I edited the question with a working fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following on `.app-sidebar`:

```
  display: flex; // make sidebar a flexbox
  flex-direction: column; // so it will align column direction
```

We do the thing above so we can apply flex related styling on the child.

This will make the parent or sidebar a flexbox, then add the following on `.app-menu`

```
    flex: 1; // this will take all the remaining space on the sidebar
```

and remove `padding-bottom` on `.app-menu` so the last item will stay in the bottom without the padding.

Comment: Can you explain why `flex: 1` makes the child take up all the height?

Comment: @dabadaba adding `flex: (number)` will divide the "REMAINING parts" of the parent div depends on the number. let say you have a 100% height parent with 2 childs, first child have `flex: 1` and the second have `flex: 2` - the second will take 60% percent of height while first will take 30% - it divided the space by flex, so if you do `flex: 1`  it will take all the remaining space to itself

Comment: @dabadaba This article helped me with flexbox while I was first studying it: 

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ 

- This made me very good at it.

Comment: flex:1 is shorthand for  { flex-grow: 1; flex-shrink: 1; flex-basis: 0%; }

Comment: ^^ true - I rarely use those 3 tho and just use `flex: 1` tho.

Answer (score 0):

It's right to do as it described in link you've attached. 
But you didn't set 100% height for your `ul`.
Setting `height: 100%;` to `.app-menu` class solves your problem.

Here is the working example based on your code:

https://jsfiddle.net/zewx18ps/1/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [**it would be preferable**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

Comment: That causes an unwanted overflow. It goes over the full height.

Comment: @Paulie_D I've just fixed my answer

Comment: @dabadaba As you have `.app-sidebar__user` div in your `.app-sidebar` and it takes 104px of the whole height. I guess `height: calc(100% - 104px)` will solve your problem.

Comment: Adding a fix number or using calc is not really ideal if you can just use flexbox to fix the issue. actually I don't recommend adding a fix number on style on an element that you are not sure whether you're going to add more stuff in the future. flexbox magic baby

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.app-menu {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    height: 100%;
```

if last item need to be displayed at the bottom of the page. try by setting height:100% to the ul