# Why does flex-end does not work for the last item in a list?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Like many people before me, I want to move the last child in a flex box to the flex box end.

I already found the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33924655/position-last-flex-item-at-the-end-of-container) to my question. Solution using `margin: auto`:

```
.container {
   width: 100%;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: flex-start;
}

.last-child {
  // justify-self: flex-end; why does this not work?
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

But I would like to know why `justify-self` does not work like that? `Margin: auto` feels like a hack to me. Is there no flex-box way to solve this? Does `justify-self` not work like `justify-content` but rather `justify-item` on a container level?

Thank you for your support!

Comment: "In flexbox layouts, this property is ignored (more about alignment in Flexbox)" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-self

Comment: could you please add your html code as weel?

Comment: it was a css related question, I think the html won't change anything, also it seems like this question has been asked before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60592022/gatsby-initial-rerender-on-client-side-bug

Comment: I have a solution for this using `CSS Grtid` but can't post due to the closed state of the question. Please consider reopening. My solution is: https://jsfiddle.net/cxkfnvjg/1/

Comment: So this was closed and the question referenced by @Temani is almost 5 years old. Three are zero mentions of` CSS Grid` in that answer and I think this one was closed way too soon.

Comment: @AndyHoffman how CSS grid is relevant to this question? the question is clear and asking something related to flexbox not how to do achieve something. Also the 5 yeasr old question is the most up to date question related to flexbox and I will use it to close question even in the next 5 years

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no `justify-self` property in flexbox for `flex-items` to align them on the main axis. For cross-axis, there's `align-self` property though, to align `flex-items` vertically.

If you don't like the `margin` to align `flex-items` on main axis then you also add an empty `span` tag before the last-child and give it `flex-grow: 1` css to get the same result.