# Gatsby initial rerender on client side bug

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, gatsby, server-side-rendering

So, I have been investigating this bug for a while now and I think I got to the root cause of it. I have a navbar that changes if the user is logged in or not. On server render (I am using gatsby), this property is obviously always false meaning that I will get the guest navbar from the server on initial render.

I have the following hook for checking isLoggedIn:

```
import { useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { UserContext } from '../contexts/UserContext';
import { isAuthenticated } from '../services/pilates-studio/localstorage';

const useIsLoggedIn = () => {
  const { user } = useContext(UserContext);
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(isAuthenticated);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('we update isLoggedIn');
    setIsLoggedIn(!!user || isAuthenticated);
  }, [user]);
  return isLoggedIn;
};

export default useIsLoggedIn;
```

`isAuthenticated` retrieves the access token from the localStorage, so as soon as we hydrate the application on the client, and the user is already logged in, `isAuthenticated` will result to `true`.

So the first state of isLoggedIn on the client side will be true. So we get the guest navbar form the server but since there is no state change ever, we are not rerendering the navbar even so technically the navbar state isLoggedIn has changed.

My navbar:

```
const NavBarContainer = () => {
  const isLoggedIn = useIsLoggedIn();

  return (
    <NavBar logo={Logo} menu={NavMenu} isMenuOpen={isMenuOpen}>
      <NavBarItem key="courses" label="Kurse" link={isLoggedIn ? '/courses' : '/courses/starter'} />
      <NavBarItem key="appointment" label="Termine" link="/appointment" show={isLoggedIn} />
      <NavBarItem key="trainers" label="Trainer" link="/trainers" />
      <NavBarItem key="login" label="Login" link="/login" show={!isLoggedIn} floatRight />
      <NavMenuButton key="menu" label="Menu" onClick={handleMenuClicked} icon={<UserIcon />} show={isLoggedIn} floatRight />
    </NavBar>
  );
};

export default NavBarContainer;
```

If I change the initial state of my hook to

```
const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
```

I get it to rerender but now I have a navbar that "blinks"/"flickers" on inital loading since it rerenders from guest to logged in navbar in a second. I would like to avoid that flickering.

I am quite new to SSR and gatsby. How would you solve the flickering? How can I have the inital state of isLoggedIn being set to true and still force a rerender?

Thanks for the support.

Comment: Why do you want to render `NavBarContainer` after the initial render, which already has the correct `isLoggedIn` value?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. `isLoggedIn` is `false` on SSR, it comes to the client and shows the corresponding state for `false` but the initial state on client side is `true` but it never updates since there was no state change (SSR state cannot be detected).

Comment: No problem. Correct me if I'm wrong but when the page gets hydrated all components render, so in this cycle we would need to figure out if it is the first render on the client, right? In this case we need to use a dependency in `useEffect` that changed when rendering from server to browser. Take a look at [this hook](https://github.com/alex-cory/use-ssr) which seems to be checking for the existence of `window.document.createElement`. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, the hooks sounds very promising!