# ¿How do I align the checkboxs like the design?

Tags: css, reactjs, layout, position

Im working on this layout, this is the design [image]

But i just cant align the checkboxes like the design so mine looks like this [image]

Here is the code so you can tell me what im doing wrong and what should i actually do...

````
  line,
}) {
  return (
    <Row
      width="35em"
    >
      <Text
        color="#73737D"
        fontSize="14px"
      >
        {line}

      </Text>
      <Box
        marginLeft="5em"
        display="flex"
        flexDirection="row"
        justifyContent="center"
        alignItems="center"
        width="2em"
      >
        <CheckBox />
      </Box>
    </Row>
  );
}```

Thanks a lot for your help!
````

Comment: You can achieve this using 'flexbox' , check this link for more details : 
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ 
,
also, the answer on the following question might help you too 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33924655/position-last-flex-item-at-the-end-of-container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use some flexbox style:

```
<Row width="35em" style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
  ...
  <Box>
    <CheckBox />
  </Box>
</Row>
```