# Align an element to the bottom within a flexbox, without using position:absolute

Tags: html, css, flexbox

See jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/q3ob7h1o/1/
Or just read it here if you'd rather:

#### Code

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-align-content: flex-end;
  align-content: flex-end;
}
.tile {
  width: 33%;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}
.content {
  background: beige;
}
.footer {
  background: teal;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="tile">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="photo"></div>
      <h3>This is some long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long content</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      <input type="submit" />
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="tile">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="photo"></div>
      <h3>This is some content</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      <input type="submit" />
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="tile">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="photo"></div>
      <h3>This is some content</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      <input type="submit" />
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

#### What I am trying to do

What I am trying to do is have the `.footer` div align to the bottom of each of the `.tile` elements, so that regardless of the amount of content in each tile, the footers line up.

I know I can use `position: absolute` on the footer but I would rather avoid this as the height of the footer might not be known.

I tried turning `.tile` into a flexbox itself and setting its direction to column, but this didn't work. I also tried turning each tile into a table-cell but this didn't work either.

The bit that is throwing me is that I am trying to target an element within one of the children of an existing flexbox. Any flexbox properties I apply apply to `.tile`, not `.footer`

Help greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Align an element to bottom with flexbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31000885/align-an-element-to-bottom-with-flexbox)

Comment: The difference is that I already have a flexbox in place. I want to align an element within one of the flexbox children.

Comment: Once you've played a bit with flexbox, this single page by CSS Tricks is very useful: [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) (flex container on left, flex items on right)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following solution:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-align-content: flex-end;
  align-content: flex-end;
}
.tile {
  width: 33%;
  display: flex;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction:column;
}
.content {
  background: beige;
}
.footer {
  background: teal;

}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="tile">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="photo"></div>
      <h3>This is some long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long content</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      <input type="submit" />
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="tile">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="photo"></div>
      <h3>This is some content</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      <input type="submit" />
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="tile">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="photo"></div>
      <h3>This is some content</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      <input type="submit" />
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The updated fiddle you can find here: https://jsfiddle.net/q3ob7h1o/2/

Comment: Perfect. Thanks very much! The bit I was missing was `justify-content: space-between`