# Flexbox stick item to bottom

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following layout.

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="content">          
       <div class="post">post</div>
       <div class="image">image</div>      
   </div>
   <div class="footer">footer</div>    
</div>
```

http://jsbin.com/xicatoq/4/edit?html,css,output

The thing I want to achieve is to make the footer stick to the bottom (I don't want to use absolute positioning) and make the `.content` stretch from the top to the footer, like in the image below.

Can someone explain how I can achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Align an element to bottom with flexbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31000885/align-an-element-to-bottom-with-flexbox)

Comment: no, i want flexbox

Comment: the solutions on that page use flexbox

Answer (score 3):

In your code, the div with class `content` is a flex container. That makes the child elements (`.post` and `.image`) flex items.

However, your div with class `container` *is not* a flex container. So `.content` and `.footer` are not flex items, and cannot accept flex properties.

So, first step, add this:

```
.container {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
}
```

Then use flex `auto` margins to stick the footer to the bottom of the container:

```
.footer {
    margin-top: auto;
}
```

Here's the full code:

```css
body {
  font-family: monospace;
  color: #fff;
  text-align:center;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  background: red;
  display: flex;          /* NEW */
  flex-direction: column; /* NEW */
}
.content {
  /* float: left; */
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.post {
  width: 70%;
  background: pink;
  line-height: 300px;
}
.image {
  width: 30%;
  height: 500px;
  background: green;
}
.footer {
  background: blue;
  line-height: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  /* float: left; */
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: auto;     /* NEW */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="content">
       <div class="post">post</div>
       <div class="image">image</div>
   </div>
   <div class="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

### [Revised Demo](http://jsbin.com/bufusogopo/1/edit?html,css,output)

Note that I commented out the floats. They aren't working. [In a flex container floats are ignored.](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/CR-css-flexbox-1-20160301/#flex-containers)

Learn more about `auto` margins here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276

Answer (score 1):

Check this : http://jsbin.com/dojitevoye/edit?html,css,output

```
body {
  font-family: monospace;
  color: #fff;
  text-align:center;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  background: red;
}

.content {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.post {
  width: 70%;
  background: pink;
  line-height: 300px;
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.image {
  width: 30%;
  height: 500px;
  background: green;
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.footer {
  background: blue;
  line-height: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  align-self:flex-end;
}
```

Set the height for the `.content` class to 100%, which will take the height of it's parent ( which is `.container` ), which will be 800px in this case.

Now align both `.post` and `.image` to the top of the parent flexbox with `align-self: flex-start;`

Now, similarly set the .footer to the bottom of flexbox using `align-self:flex-end;`

Answer (score 0):

Just use `height: 100%;` to `.content` will make footer stick to bottom.

**[Working JSBin](http://jsbin.com/xaqonasabo/edit?html,css,output)**

Comment: Yeah, this works. It may not be a preferred solution (that's up to the OP), but it gets the job done. No reason to downvote. I'll balance it out.