# Positioning a flex item to the bottom of the flex-container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm quite new to flexbox. What I can't seem to figure out is how to position a div to the bottom of the flex container. I searched for solutions on stack overflow but nothing works. Clearly I'm doing something wrong.

So the div **header-bottom** should be positioned at the bottom of the **header** container. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Website</title>

        <!-- STYLESHEETS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <!-- FONTS -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playball|Raleway: 300,900" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <header class="header">
            <div class="header-logo">
                <a href="/">
                    <img class="header-logo-img" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="">
                </a>
            </div>
            <nav class="header-nav-primary" role="navigation">
                <ul class="nav-primary-items">
                    <li class="nav-primary-item">
                        <a class="nav-primary-link" href="#home">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-primary-item">
                        <a class="nav-primary-link" href="#menu">Menu</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-primary-item">
                        <a class="nav-primary-link" href="#over">Over</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-primary-item">
                        <a class="nav-primary-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <div class="header-bottom">
                <div class="social-media">
                    <a href="http://www.facebook.be" target="_blank">
                        <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </a>
                    <a href="http://www.instagram.be" target="_blank">
                        <i class="fa fa-instagram fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="address">
                    <p>Diestsesteenweg ###<br>3010 Kessel-Lo<br>###/## ## ##</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <main class="main">
            <section id="home"></section>
            <section id="menu"></section>
            <section id="over"></section>
            <section id="contact"></section>
        </main>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
    min-width: 320px;
    background-color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    color: #f1ebda;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.8;
}

.wrapper {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-width: 100vw;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

.header {
    padding: 2.75rem;
    background-color: #303030;
}

.header-logo {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-bottom: 5.625rem;
}

.nav-primary-items {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 0 1.250rem 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.nav-primary-item {
    margin: 0 .4rem;
}

.nav-primary-link {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 .4rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0.188rem;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
}

.header-bottom {
    text-align: center;
}

.social-media i {
    margin-right: 1.250rem;
}

.address p {
    margin: 1.250rem 0 0 0;

}

.main {
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 4.45rem 2.75rem;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    margin: 0 0 1.05rem;
    padding: 0;
    color: #111;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1.2;
    font-family: 'Playball', sans-serif;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #f1ebda;
}

a:active, 
a:hover,
a:focus {
    color: #f1ebda;
    text-decoration: none;
}

@media (min-width: 840px) {
    .wrapper {
        -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
        -webkit-flex-direction: row;
        -ms-flex-direction: row;
        flex-direction: row;
        overflow: hidden;
        height: 100vh;
    }

    .header {
        -webkit-box-flex: 0;
        -webkit-flex: 0 0 32rem;
        -ms-flex: 0 0 32rem;
        flex: 0 0 32rem;
        padding: 4.45rem 2.75rem;
        max-width: 32rem;
    }

    .header-nav-primary {
        margin-bottom: 2.75rem;
    }

    .nav-primary-items {
        -webkit-flex-flow: column nowrap;
        -ms-flex-flow: column nowrap;
        flex-flow: column;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .nav-primary-item {
        margin-bottom: 3.125em;
    }

    .nav-primary-link {
        display: block;
        padding: .4rem;
    }

    .main {
        -webkit-box-flex: 1;
        -webkit-flex: 1;
        -ms-flex: 1;
        flex: 1;
        padding: 4.45rem;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31000885/align-an-element-to-bottom-with-flexbox

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. The `.header-bottom` div is in fact at the bottom of the `.header` container (even in the media query): https://jsfiddle.net/9bckrv3q/1/

Comment: Open it in a new window. It's not positioned to the bottom...

Comment: Aside from that, keep in mind that `.header-bottom` is not a flex item, and `.header` is not a flex container. http://stackoverflow.com/a/37844240/3597276

Comment: Ok I see now I'll keep trying.

Answer (score -1):

Just add:

`align-self: flex-end;` to the element you want to position on the bottom.

---

These are great guides to flexbox if you want to learn some other cool tricks:

http://flexbox.io/

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score -1):

Use this code below:

```
.header-bottom{
    align-self: flex-end;
    text-align: center;
}
```

See this tutorial: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/