# flexbox sticky footer

Tags: css, flexbox, height, sticky-footer

I'm trying to achieve more or less the same of what is described in this question:

- [Align an element to bottom with flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31000885/align-an-element-to-bottom-with-flexbox)

except for the fact that i can't use fixed heights.

I have set of two cards that are already in a flex context (their heights are stretched with flexbox):

[image]

Inside the card I have a series of elements:

- a header
- a body
- a footer (the blue div)

What I want is the footer to always stick to the bottom.

The inner container of the three elements described above have the following CSS:

```
.card-inner {
  display:flex;
  flex-flow :row wrap;
  align-items: stretch;
}
```

and the items inside have

```
.card {
  &-header,
  &-body {
    flex: 0 1 100%;
  }
  &-footer {
    flex: 0 1 100%;
    align-self:flex-end;
    margin-top: auto;
  }
}
```

I would have expected that `align-self:flex-end` or `margin-top: auto` would have pushed the footer div down the card, but this is not happening.

Maybe the two flex contexts don't *speak* to each other and are not related? Or maybe without a height to the inner container, the flex context ends when the content flow ends?

Is there a way to achieve this using no heights with flexbox?

Here's a codepen example: https://codepen.io/vlrprbttst/pen/QgWbEr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `display: flex` to `.card`.

That will allow the children to use the full height of `.container`.

It will also pin the footer to the bottom.

[revised demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WONvWL)

---

For a more comprehensive fix (if necessary), you will need to switch the `flex-direction` of  `.container-inner` to `column`, and make adjustments to the flex items to account for this switch.

[revised demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QgWbeo)

---

The reason why `align-self: flex-end` and `margin-top: auto` didn't work has to do with the flex lines in a multi-line flex container.

Essentially, because of the way `align-content` works, your footer cannot break out of its flex line and shift to the bottom of the container.

For a complete explanation, see this post:

- [How does flex-wrap work with align-self, align-items and align-content?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42613359/3597276)