# CSS class align-self-end not working

Tags: css, html, flexbox, bootstrap-4

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="card bg-dark text-white">
    <img class="card-img" src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x340" alt="Card image">
    <div class="card-img-overlay">
      <h5 class="card-title">Title</h5>
      <h3 class="card-text font-weight-bold"><span class="mr-auto">Some other title here</span></h3>
      <div class="align-self-end">Text I want at bottom</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am unable to get the text in the last div by applying this class `align-self-end` to the bottom of the image. I understand that flex has been applied to the `.card-img-overlay` div with the direction of column then why am I unable to get the div to the bottom of the image?

Comment: You can read here about how `align-self` etc. works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42613359/how-does-flex-wrap-work-with-align-self-align-items-and-align-content

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `card-img-overlay` div isn't `display:flex`.

You can do this by adding the `d-flex flex-column` classes to it, and use `mt-auto` to push the text to the bottom.

https://www.codeply.com/go/SRdCTDDoRr

```
<div class="card bg-dark text-white">
       <img class="card-img" src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x340" alt="Card image">
       <div class="card-img-overlay d-flex flex-column">
            <h5 class="card-title">Title</h5>
            <h3 class="card-text font-weight-bold"><span class="mr-auto">Some other title here</span></h3>
            <div class="mt-auto">Text I want at bottom</div>
       </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, that worked. But can you also tell me why align-self-end doesn't work? It aligns it to the right instead of bottom.

Comment: It's [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31000885/align-an-element-to-bottom-with-flexbox) and elsewhere. Basically, you could get `align-self-end` to work along with `justify-content-between` but the you'd have to restructure the card more. Auto margins are just easier.