# Aligning div to bottom of page without using position absolute or fixed

Tags: css, alignment, footer, fixed, absolute

Any ideas on how to position a div or a footer without using position absolute or fixed? If I use absolute, it overflows the content at smaller screens and I do not want to use fixed as I do not want the footer to visable at all times. I would be grateful for any tips or tricks. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Flexbox is probably easiest --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31000885/align-an-element-to-bottom-with-flexbox.

Comment: please go through all the answers of the duplicate question before claiming it's not a duplicate