# Align the green button at the end of each div in css

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have this "buy" (comprar) button that I'd like to put in the end of div so they would be align with each other "buy" button.

eg:

```
button button button
```

not:

```
button            button
       button
```

```css
#content01{
 min-height:500px;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.produto{
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #F6F6F6;
  width: 246px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding-bottom:10px;
}


.comprar_button {
  background: green;
  padding:10px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align:center;
  font-weight:bold;
  vertical-align:bottom;
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.comprar_button a{
  color: #fff!important;
}

.comprar_button img{
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content01">
    
  <div class="produto">Some text<br><br><br><b>$ 20.00</b><br><br>
      <br><span class="comprar_button">COMPRAR</span>
  </div>

  <div class="produto">Some text text some text some text some text<br><br><br><b>$ 20.00</b><br><br>
      <br><span class="comprar_button">COMPRAR</span>
  </div>

  <div class="produto">Some text<br><br><br><b>$ 20.00</b><br><br>
      <br><span class="comprar_button">COMPRAR</span>
  </div>

  <div class="produto">Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text<br><br><br><b>$ 20.00</b><br><br>
      <br><span class="comprar_button">COMPRAR</span>
  </div>

</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j72u8Lx5/

how can I align the "comprar" button?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Align an element to bottom with flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31000885/align-an-element-to-bottom-with-flexbox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign `display: flex` also to your `.produto` DIVs, with `flex-direction: column` and `align-items: center`. Then add `margin-top: auto` to the `.comprar_button` to move it to the bottom of the container (and remove some other, superfluous stuff, see below):

```css
#content01{
 min-height:500px;
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.produto{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #F6F6F6;
  width: 246px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom:10px;
}


.comprar_button {
  background: green;
  padding:10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight:bold;
  margin-top: auto;
}

.comprar_button a{
  color: #fff!important;
}

.comprar_button img{
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content01">
    
  <div class="produto">Some text<br><br><br><b>$ 20.00</b><br><br>
      <br><span class="comprar_button">COMPRAR</span>
  </div>

  <div class="produto">Some text text some text some text some text<br><br><br><b>$ 20.00</b><br><br>
      <br><span class="comprar_button">COMPRAR</span>
  </div>

  <div class="produto">Some text<br><br><br><b>$ 20.00</b><br><br>
      <br><span class="comprar_button">COMPRAR</span>
  </div>

  <div class="produto">Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text<br><br><br><b>$ 20.00</b><br><br>
      <br><span class="comprar_button">COMPRAR</span>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want? It used position absolute.

https://jsfiddle.net/usv7jLhm/

```
.produto{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 2px solid #F6F6F6;
    width: 246px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding-bottom:10px;
}

.comprar_button {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background: green;
    padding:10px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    align-self: flex-end;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using **flex** I commented the changes I did in the code :
https://jsfiddle.net/3jenapsb

```css
#content01{
 min-height:500px;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.produto{
  
  display: flex;/*added*/
  flex-direction:column;/*added*/
  align-items:center;/*added*/
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #F6F6F6;
  width: 246px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding-bottom:10px;
}

b{
  flex-grow:1;/*added*/
}

.comprar_button {
 background: green;
 padding:10px;
 color: #fff;
 text-align:center;
 font-weight:bold;
 vertical-align:bottom;
 width:150px;/*added*/
}
.comprar_button a{
 color: #fff!important;
}
.comprar_button img{
 width: 15px;
 height: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content01">

<div class="produto">Some text<br><br><br><b>$ 20.00</b><br><br>
  <br><span class="comprar_button">COMPRAR</span>
</div>
    
<div class="produto">Some text text some text some text some text<br><br><br><b>$ 20.00</b><br><br>
  <br><span class="comprar_button">COMPRAR</span>
</div>

<div class="produto">Some text<br><br><br><b>$ 20.00</b><br><br>
  <br><span class="comprar_button">COMPRAR</span>
</div>

<div class="produto">Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text<br><br><br><b>$ 20.00</b><br><br>
  <br><span class="comprar_button">COMPRAR</span>
</div>
   
   
   </div>
```