# extending div to fit screen

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a function which pushes my footer to the bottom of the page. It works by adding a margin to the top of the footer, however, i want to add a bg color to my content and with the margin this just leaves a big whitespace in the middle.

Can I extend the div above instead of adding the margin to the footer so that my bg color covers the page with no whitespace.

```js
if ($('#footer').length) {
  var doc_height = $(window).height();
  var footer_top = $('#footer').position().top + $('#footer').height();
  
  if (footer_top < doc_height) {
    $('#footer').css('margin-top', (doc_height - footer_top) + 'px');
  }
}
```

```css
#main_content {
  background-color: #f00
}

#footer {
  background-color: #0f0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main_content">Some text</div>
<div id="footer">Some text</div>
```

Comment: Why would you use js for this? Flex should work just fine

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Align an element to bottom with flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31000885/align-an-element-to-bottom-with-flexbox)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try flex as shown below:

```css
#main_content{background-color:#f00}
#footer{background-color:#0f0}
body{
display:flex;
flex-direction:column;
height:100vh;
}
#main_content{
flex-basis:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main_content">Some text</div>
<div id="footer">Some text</div>
```

Comment: Why the `doc_height` var?

Comment: Yeah not needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it *without* `JavaScript`. See the demo of my answer.

By using this code

- You don't see an useless `scroll bar` beside the page when your content is little.
- `div` elements are fitted to the page.
- The `main_content` and `footer` will be stretched when their content is large.

**Demo**

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  height:100vh;
}
#main_content{
  min-height:90%;
  background-color:#f00;
 }
#footer{
  min-height:10%;
  background-color:#0f0;
}
```

```html
<div id="main_content">Some text</div>
<div id="footer">Some text</div>
```